# How can I cast <T> as Enum when using EnumToList<T>

Tags: c#, types, enums

I have a simple class `SelectItemOption` that is used generically in dropdowns, lists, etc.

```
public class SelectItemOption
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a method that populates a `List<SelectItemOption>` with values from an Enum.  `GetDisplayName()` and `GetDisplayDescription()` get this info from the attributes.

I robbed some code from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154335/1778169) to get the enum values into an enumerable.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> EnumToList<T>()
        where T : struct
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    }
```

I am attempting to put it all together like this:

```
    public static List<SelectItemOption> EnumAsSelectItemOptions<T>()
        where T : struct
    {
        var optionsList = new List<SelectItemOption>();
        foreach (var option in EnumToList<T>())   //** headache here **
        {
            optionsList.Add(new SelectItemOption()
            {
                Title = option.GetDisplayName(),
                ID = option.ToString(),
                Description = option.GetDisplayDescription()
            });
        }
        return optionsList;
    }
```

The problem occurs when I try to iterate EnumToList.

*No matter what I try, I can't seem to get the `option` variable to act like an Enum.*

**I've Tried...**

If I use `foreach (Enum option in EnumToList<T>())` I get "cannot convert type T to system.enum".

But if I use `foreach (var option in EnumToList<T>())` my extension methods aren't recognised.

If I try to cast `option` as an Enum after the foreach statement I get "cannot implicitly convert type T to system.enum".

Aaaaggggghhhhh!

Comment: That's because `option` isn't an `enum`, it's a `T : struct`.

Comment: `EnumToList` will return an enumerable of `T`s. That's just how you've written it. The items you get aren't of type `Enum`, they're of whatever type of enum you're passing as the generic type argument to `EnumAsSelectItemOptions`.

Comment: E.g. if you're calling `EnumAsSelectItemOptions<SelectItemOption>()`, each `option` is of type `SelectItemOption`.

Comment: This may be a daft question, but Is there not way to cast or convert the T so it's recognised as an Enum?  I don't *think* it's possible to have an enum constraint instead of struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't constrain as `Enum` so `option` can only be a `struct`. However, you could try write your `EnumAsSelectItemOptions` method something like this:

```
public static List<SelectItemOption> EnumAsSelectItemOptions<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    var optionsList = new List<SelectItemOption>();
    foreach (var option in EnumToList<T>())   //** headache here **
    {
        optionsList.Add(new SelectItemOption()
        {
            Title = option is Enum
                ? (option as Enum).GetDisplayName()
                : option.ToString(),
            ID = option.ToString(),
            Description = option is Enum
                ? (option as Enum).GetDisplayDescription()
                : option.ToString(),
        });
    }
    return optionsList;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. You have solved a 2 hr headache in just under 6 minutes.