# Assigning a random enum value a property

Tags: c#, enums

Hi have been given a task that I am struggling with. I need to assign a random `enum` to a property. The code I have is this.

```
public enum PegColour
{
    Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Black, White
}
```

And other class which looks like this

```
public class PegContainer
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Dfines the colour of the first peg
   /// </summary>
    public Peg Colour1 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dfines the colour of the secod peg
    /// </summary>
    public Peg Colour2 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dfines the colour of the third peg
    /// </summary>
    public Peg Colour3 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dfines the colour of the forth peg
    /// </summary>
    public Peg Colour4 { get; set; }

    public void GeneratePegs()
    {

    }
}
```

my `GeneratePegs()` method should, each time it is called randomly assign one of the `enum` colours to one of the properties (`Colour1`, `Colour2` etc.) to complicate matters I need the randomizer to ignore `Black` and `White`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums are just integers and therefore integers can be cast to an enum. I would do this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

public enum PegColour
{
    Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Black, White
}

private PegColour GetRandomColoredPeg()
{
    PegColour color = (PegColour)rnd.Next(0, Enum.GetNames(typeof(PegColour)).Length - 2);
    return color;
}
```

Black and White will never get selected because it only picks randomly from the first 4 colors. As long as you add pegs BEFORE the black and white pegs, this code should work every time, even if you add or remove pegs from the enumeration. So if you wanted to add new colors, you'd just change `PegColour` to something like this:

```
public enum PegColour
{
    Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Purple, Orange, Pink, Black, White
}
```

You wouldn't need to change anything else!

So your `GeneratePegs()` method should just look like this:

```
public void GeneratePegs()
{
    Colour1 = GetRandomColoredPeg();
    Colour2 = GetRandomColoredPeg();
    Colour3 = GetRandomColoredPeg();
    Colour4 = GetRandomColoredPeg();
}
```

Comment: Let's hope no-one overzealously starts sorting those `enum` constants alphabetically ;-)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - ^^ Good one. I can't, for the life of me, think of any advantageous reason to sort an `enum`. If they do, just name the colors `ZBlack` and `ZWhite` lol

Comment: Seeing the enum constants in the same order in code and in the docs (where they are usually sorted alphabetically) could be a reason. Being able to quickly find (in a large enum) a particular constant in code might be another.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution could be creating an array that contains all the eligible values:

```
PegColour[] eligibleValues = new[] { PegColour.Red, PegColour.Blue, PegColour.Green, PegColour.Yellow };
```

You could then use an instance of [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.random%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to randomly pick an index in that array:

```
var myRandomColour = eligibleValues[myRandom.Next(eligibleValues.Length)];
```

An advantage of this is that you do not have to assign any specific numeric values to the `enum` constants for the random selection to work. This way, you are still free to define and use the numeric values for another purpose, if required.

---

Now, this *might* still be a little inconvenient in case `PegColour` frequently gets extended with new elements. In that case, you can retrieve the full list of currently defined constants once upon initialization from the [`Enum.GetValues` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (note that this code snippet assumes the [`System.Linq` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has been imported to allow accessing the extension methods from [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
PegColour[] eligibleValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PegColour)).Cast<PegColour>().ToArray();
```

Obviously, this doesn't yet fulfil the requirement that certain colours be excluded. You can, thus, either hard-code this restriction directly in the array creation expression:

```
PegColour[] eligibleValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PegColour)).Cast<PegColour>().Where(pc => (pc != PegColour.Black) && (pc != PegColour.White)).ToArray();
```

... or store the colours to exclude in some [set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make things more extensible:

```
PegColour[] eligibleValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PegColour)).Cast<PegColour>().Where(pc => !myExcludedColours.Contains(pc)).ToArray();
```

Note that you can always place this code so as to initialize `eligibleValues` just once, rather than each time you randomly retrieve a value. This avoids unnecessary [possibly costly calls to `GetValues`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154513/1430156), as well as needlessly generating the array anew all the time.

Comment: I like this solution, as it is easily expandable.  Allows any number of pegs, as well as any number of eligible values.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a list:

```
var pegs = new List<Peg> { Peg.Red, Peg.Green, Peg.Blue, Peg.Yellow };
```

Then using [the accepted answer to this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)n, randomly order it. Finally, assign the values to the pegs:

```
Colour1 = pages[0];
Colour2 = pages[1];
Colour3 = pages[2];
Colour4 = pages[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a very general extension method for a `Random` object that produces a random value of an `Enum` type.  This works for all sorts of messed-up enums, including ones with terrible numbering schemes.  This is achieved by using `Enum.GetValues` to get all possible values of the Enum.  Then the random just picks a random possible value.

```
public static TEnum GetRandomEnum<TEnum>(this Random rand, IEnumerable<TEnum> excludedValues)
{
    var type = typeof(TEnum);
    if (!type.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum type");


    var values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<TEnum>();

    if (excludedValues != null && excludedValues.Any())
        values = values.Except(excludedValues); 
    //if you call this a lot, you could consider saving this collection in memory
    //   and separate the logic to avoid having to re-generate the collection


    //create a random index for each possible Enum value 
    //will never be out of bounds because it NextDouble returns a value
    //between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)  or [0, 1)
    int randomIndex = (int) (rand.NextDouble() * values.Count());
    return values.ElementAt(randomIndex);
}
```

This extension method is call like this:

```
var randomColor = rand.GetRandomEnum<ColorType>(new List<Colors> 
{ 
    Colors.White, 
    Colors.Black
});
```

[A demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Im0rSx).

Comment: How does this exclude some of the enum values, as requested in the question?