# How do I bind an enum to my listbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a Silverlight (WP7) project and would like to bind an enum to a listbox. This is an enum with custom values, sitting in a class library. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Databinding an enum property to a ComboBox in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Silverlight(WP7), Enum.GetNames() method is not available. You can use the following

```
public class Enum<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Type '" + type.Name + "' is not an enum");

        return (
          from field in type.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
          where field.IsLiteral
          select field.Name).ToList<string>();
    }
}
```

The static method will returns enumerable string collection. You can bind that to a listbox's itemssource. Like

```
this.listBox1.ItemSource = Enum<Colors>.GetNames();
```

Comment: Then, the next question is, how do you assign, with binding, the selected enum value back to a property in the viewmodel? I've been looking around for answers, but couldn't find any resource, any direction pointing is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: @K2so You can have a property in the view model bound to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox`. check the following sample that could help you. https://sites.google.com/site/html5tutorials/BindingEnum.zip

Comment: Mind if I borrow this code and attribute to you in my PhoneyTools project so people can use it?  http://phoney.codeplex.com?

Comment: @ Shawn Wildermuth I'm honoured :) I'm a big fan of your blogs :)

Comment: What about [Description] attribute? Often it is helpful to use this when Enums need a better string representation. You are not handling that case here.

Answer (score 1):

Use a converter to do this.
Refer to http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2008/10/16/databinding-an-enum-in-wpf.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the enum to a list (or similar) - as per [How do I convert an enum to a list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/convert-enum-to-list-in-c)

then bind to the converted list.