# How to bind enum to listpicker in WP?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use so enum in WP application:

public enum gender
 {
        man = 0,
        woman,
        other
 }

how can i write code that Listpicker items are gender enum items. To tell clear, i want user to select gender from Listpicker. Please, help.

Comment: Have you tried to do something like this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935953/how-do-i-bind-an-enum-to-my-listbox

Comment: No, but now im trying, thanks

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks. but i have other problem now.
If Listpicker items count is 3 (or less 3) pistpicker opens as combobox in current page, but is more than 3 it opens other page. not as combobox. how i solve this problem?

Comment: more than 3 items in the same page would overflow, and scrolling within the combo box is not an option. You could try creating a listpicker which always opens as a full screen page.

Comment: @Ceyhun Rehimov: Set the ItemCountThreshHoldValue to your Listpicker

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to bind to a property of the enum type, like this?

```
public enum EnumType { Item1, Item2 }
public EnumType Property { get; set; }
```

This is how I did it:

(in the constructor)

```
theListPicker.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType));
```

(XAML)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    x:Name="_this"/>
    ...
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <local:EnumIntConverter x:Name="enumIntConverter"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    ....
    <toolkit:ListPicker ...
        SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Property, Converter={StaticResource enumIntConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}
```

(somewhere in your namespace)

```
public class EnumIntConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)(EnumType)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).GetValue((int)value);
    }
}
```

In my case, I also wanted to use the enum's Descriptions instead of their names, so I'm using this code instead of the "in the constructor" one-liner above:

```
Array rawValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType));
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (EnumType e in rawValues)
    values.Add((typeof(EnumType).GetMember(e.ToString())[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)[0] as DescriptionAttribute).Description);
theListPicker.ItemsSource = values;
```

Comment: Enum.GetValues is unavailable in WP7