# Convert an enum to List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, enums, generic-list

How do I convert the following Enum to a List of strings?

```
[Flags]
public enum DataSourceTypes
{
    None = 0,
    Grid = 1,
    ExcelFile = 2,
    ODBC = 4
};
```

I couldn't find this exact question, this [Enum to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c) is the closest but I specifically want `List<string>`?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Use `Enum`'s static method, [`GetNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It returns a `string[]`, like so:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(DataSourceTypes))
```

If you want to create a method that does only this for only one type of `enum`, and also converts that array to a `List`, you can write something like this:

```
public List<string> GetDataSourceTypes()
{
    return Enum.GetNames(typeof(DataSourceTypes)).ToList();
}
```

You will need `Using System.Linq;` at the top of your class to use .ToList()

---

If you only need a single item in the list:

```
string enumItemAsString = nameof(DataSourceTypes.Grid)
```

Comment: @DCShannon please do not edit popular questions/answers and shrink explanations. While you and I understand shorthand code, newbie's need all the extra details to **associate** it with their *learnings*.

Comment: It seems `Enum.GetNames(typeof(DataSourceTypes))` return a generic `System.Array` instead of a string array?

Comment: @sookie, see the msdn link, this is the signature of the **GetNames()** method: `public static string[] GetNames`

Answer (score 38):

I want to add another solution: 
In my case, I need to use a Enum group in a drop down button list items. So they might have space, i.e. more user friendly descriptions needed:

```
  public enum CancelReasonsEnum
{
    [Description("In rush")]
    InRush,
    [Description("Need more coffee")]
    NeedMoreCoffee,
    [Description("Call me back in 5 minutes!")]
    In5Minutes
}
```

In a helper class (HelperMethods) I created the following method:

```
 public static List<string> GetListOfDescription<T>() where T : struct
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        return !t.IsEnum ? null : Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<Enum>().Select(x => x.GetDescription()).ToList();
    }
```

When you call this helper you will get the list of item descriptions.

```
 List<string> items = HelperMethods.GetListOfDescription<CancelReasonEnum>();
```

ADDITION:
In any case, if you want to implement this method you need :GetDescription extension for enum. This is what I use.

```
 public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
        if (name != null)
        {
            FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
            if (field != null)
            {
                DescriptionAttribute attr =Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
                if (attr != null)
                {
                    return attr.Description;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
        /* how to use
            MyEnum x = MyEnum.NeedMoreCoffee;
            string description = x.GetDescription();
        */

    }
```

Comment: Instead of `[Description(` use `[EnumMember(Value =` which *auto deserializes* JSON Enums! Its easy to implement, change: `x => x.GetDescription()` to `x => x.GetAttributeOfType<EnumMemberAttribute>().Value` and the method: `public static T GetAttributeOfType<T>(this Enum enumVal) where T : System.Attribute
        {
            var type = enumVal.GetType();
            var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
            var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
            return (attributes.Length > 0) ? (T)attributes[0] : null;
        }`

Comment: The `GetDescription` extension should return `field.Name` if `attr` is null (in case there's no description attribute on a value).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I need to convert it as ***SelectItem*** for Checkbox and Radio Button

```
public class Enum<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public static List<SelectItem> ToSelectItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
                throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
            
            var values = Enum.GetNames(typeof(T));
            return values.Select((t, i) => new SelectItem() {Id = i, Name = t}).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```