# Enum to Dictionary LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, enums

I'm trying to convert an Enumeration to a Dictionary using LINQ

Here is what I have so far:

```
// returns a dictionary populated with the relevant keys
public Dictionary<string, string> StartNewEntry()
{
    return Enum.GetNames(typeof(TableDictionary)).ToDictionary(Key => 
                         (string)Enum.Parse(typeof(TableDictionary), Key), value => "");
}
```

Its giving me issues when trying to cast the key.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'InventoryImportExportLibrary.TableDictionary' to type 'System.String'.
```

I'm looking for this:

```
public enum TableDictionary
{
    Barcode = 0,
    FullName = 1,
    Location = 2,
    Notes = 3,
    Category = 4,
    Timestamp = 5,
    Description = 6
}
```

With a dictionary thats

["Barcode", ""]

I'm not sure what suits does here. I do want the string because I need to use it later in my program for comparisons.

Comment: Why are you using `Enum.Parse` at all, if you only want strings? It would help if you'd explain what you want compared with the previous answer I gave you - an example of an enum along with the expected dictionary entries would be useful, for example.

Comment: So far you've said that you wrote some code and got some errors. What is your specific question?

Comment: How do I set this up correctly? I don't understand the types.

Answer (score 0):

I think want you really want is 
Enum to List See: [Convert an enum to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971631/convert-an-enum-to-liststring)

But if you really need a Dictionary take a look at [Enum to Dictionary c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583717/enum-to-dictionary-c-sharp)