# How to loop through a static class of constants?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

Instead of using a Switch statement as shown in the code below, is there an alternative way to check if `foo.Type` is a match to any of the constants in the `Parent.Child` class?

The intended goal is to loop through all of the constant values to see if `foo.Type` is a match, rather than having to specify each constant as a `case`.

Parent Class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public static class Child
    {
        public const string JOHN = "John";
        public const string MARY = "Mary";
        public const string JANE = "Jane";
    }
}
```

Code:

```
switch (foo.Type)
{
     case Parent.Child.JOHN:
     case Parent.Child.MARY:
     case Parent.Child.JANE:
         // Do Something
         break;
}
```

Comment: can you define all the constants in an array, and loop through that array to check constant values?

Comment: You can put all the constant values in an ArrayList, iterate over the list while comparing if a particular element is equal to foo.Type.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971631/convert-an-enum-to-liststring, then just do an **IndexOf(foo.Type)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) you can find all constant values in the class:

```
var values = typeof(Parent.Child).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                 .Where(x => x.IsLiteral && !x.IsInitOnly)
                                 .Select(x => x.GetValue(null)).Cast<string>();
```

Then you can check if values contains something:

```
if(values.Contains("something")) {/**/}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can loop through constants that are declared like that using reflection (as the other answers show), it's not ideal.

It would be much more efficient to store them in some kind of enumerable object: an array, List, ArrayList, whatever fits your requirements best.

Something like:

```
public class Parent {
    public static List<string> Children = new List<string> {"John", "Mary", "Jane"}
}
```

Then:

```
if (Parent.Children.Contains(foo.Type) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get all constants of given class:

```
var type = typeof(Parent.Child);
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

var constants = fieldInfos.Where(f => f.IsLiteral && !f.IsInitOnly).ToList();
var constValue = Console.ReadLine();
var match = constants.FirstOrDefault(c => (string)c.GetRawConstantValue().ToString() == constValue.ToString());
```