# How to create a dictionary in c# which can store Type as value

Tags: c#

I am trying to store a Enum class Type as value in Dictionary but i am getting **'Test' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.** basically Test is Enum Class.

```
public enum Test
    {
        Test1 = 1,
        Test2 = 2,
    }

and Dictionary:-
private Dictionary<int, Type> _typeMapping;
```

Comment: Maybe you need `typeof(Test)`?

Comment: How are you trying to add the enum to the dictionary?

Comment: _typeMapping.Add(1,Test)

Comment: Apart from the `and Dictionary:-` there is nothing wrong with the code in you question https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMoBuPPVAZhPSIGE8BvPIjogBwCcBLAG4BDAC4BTIgBE+AYxF8A9gDshPAJ4AePkpEwiAFTVcxAPiIB9EUbEBZIVy7aA5pVyci7TrRJQiNgBQAlJ4cbG6cAL54UbjUdGJKAK4AtgZiAM4iIURh7u76GSKYRAC8RJgw2fmFDGXoleEcMUA

Comment: Personally I don't think you need to save the Type, you can look up the Name of the Enum by Value, so you only need a List<int>: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14971637/495455

Comment: Actually i have to map a list of Enum.

Comment: @Arvind If that is what you need to do show that code and perhaps we can help you to do it in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you are doing something like this:

```
_typeMapping.Add(1, Test);
```

When you should do this:

```
_typeMapping.Add(1, typeof(Test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<int, Type> TypeMapping { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TypeMapping = new Dictionary<int, Type>();
        Test test1 = Test.Test1;
        TypeMapping.Add((int)test1, test1.GetType());
    }
}

public enum Test
{
    Test1 = 1,
    Test2 = 2
}
```