# Converting an Enum to a list

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have an enum defined as

```
public enum SecurityRole
{
    Admin = 0,
    ViewLog = 1,
    DeleteLog = 2
}
```

and want to use the technique described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c)  to get a `List<SecurityRole>`.

Thus the line

```
var lst = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SecurityRole)).Cast<SecurityRole>().ToList();
```

should work, but IntelliSense wont allow the .ToList property

I am using `System.Linq`. Is there some other reference I need?

Comment: Your code is valid, and executes successfully. As a shot in the dark, maybe Visual Studio is confused? Are there compilation errors, or just IntelliSense failures? Try relaunching VS.

Comment: @kirsten it works for me and this is the correct syntax, see the official question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c - Can you delete the `.` before `ToList()` and press the `.` if that fails press Ctrl+Space to bring up intellisense

Comment: just try to rebuild the solution and try again because ur code should work since you use: `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using System.Linq` should do it. `ToList()` is an `IEnumerable<T>` extension method. Probably check if you have any other compilation errors in your code.

Comment: `Cast<T>` is also defined in `Enumerable` class

Comment: There were compiler errors. It works now they have been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Check the solution here: [How do I convert an enum to a list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c)

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)).Cast<SomeEnum>();
```

Comment: That will return an `IEnumerable<SomeEnum>`. To return a `List<SomeEnum>`, answers there recommend calling `ToList()`, just as the OP here has done.