# How to Declare a List<> of Enums in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums

I need to declare a List of Enums and I can't figure out how to do it right.

This is my code so far:

```
public enum Languages
{
    Ger,Eng,Fra,Ita,Rus
}

public class Player
{
    public string ID { get; private set; }
    private List<Languages> Languages;

    public Player(string ID, List<Languages> LangList)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Languages = LangList;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player PlayerA = new Player("Player A", **[Problem is here]**);
    }
}
```

As you can see the constructor of Player expects a list of languages that are supported by the player. I wanted to define the possible Languages as enums. Now i don't know how i declare such a list in the construction call.

I know i could just do it like this:

```
        List<FoolMeLib.Languages> pLang = new List<FoolMeLib.Languages>;
        pLang.Add(FoolMeLib.Languages.Ger);
        pLang.Add(FoolMeLib.Languages.Eng);
        NewGame.AddPlayer(new FoolMeLib.Player("Player A", pLang));
```

but i want to write the code as sleek as possible... Btw: if you see any other bad practice: tell me. I'm triing to improve.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c)

Comment: Try `public Player(string ID, IEnumerable<Languages> LangList)` and pass an array with `new[] { Language.Ger, Language.Eng }`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without code changes to `Player`, you could do:

```
NewGame.AddPlayer(new FoolMeLib.Player("Player A",
    new List<FoolMeLib.Language> {
        FoolMeLib.Languages.Ger, FoolMeLib.Languages.Eng
}));
```

If you ware open to changes, a `params FoolMeLib.Languages[] languages` parameter would allow:

```
NewGame.AddPlayer(new FoolMeLib.Player("Player A",
    FoolMeLib.Languages.Ger, FoolMeLib.Languages.Eng));
```

Or if you allow the enum to be a `[Flags]` - just one parameter is needed:

```
NewGame.AddPlayer(new FoolMeLib.Player("Player A",
    FoolMeLib.Languages.Ger | FoolMeLib.Languages.Eng));
```

(But they would need specific numbers in the 2<sup>n</sup> range)

Answer (score 2):

Good options for collection initializer have been posted.

Another options could be to use flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum Languages { Ger = 1,Eng = 2,Fra = 4,Ita = 8, Rus = 16 }

// ctor
public Player(string id, Languages languages) {}

// call
new Player("Player A", Languages.Eng | Languages.Fra);
```

Depending on what you plan to do with the languages this might be a good or a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

I think your title and question are misleading, you might actually be looking for `params`.

For example if you redefine you constructor like:

```
public Player(string ID, params Languages[] languages)
{
   Languages = languages.ToList();
}
```

You can pass the languages you support as a list of parameters

```
new Player("Player A", Languages.Ger, Languages.Eng)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Languages)).Cast<Languages>();
```

Comment: He doesn't want all languages.

Answer (score 0):

**Your question:**

How to call the constructor with the list of languages?

**The sleekest possible way:**

E.g. you have a player who can speak english and german:

```
Player PlayerA = new Player("Player A", new List<Languages> 
{ Languages.Eng, Languages.Ger });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do **not** accept to modify class Player, just call the constructor like this:

```
new Player("Player A", new List<Languages> { Languages.Ger, Languages.Eng });
```

If you **do** accept to modify class Player, use params and change type of Languages to Languages[]:

```
public enum Languages
{
    Ger, Eng, Fra, Ita, Rus
}

public class Player
{
    public string ID { get; private set; }
    private Languages[] Languages;

    public Player(string ID, params Languages[] LangList)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Languages = LangList;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player PlayerA = new Player("Player A", Languages.Ger, Languages.Eng);
    }
}
```