# Get list from enum

Tags: c#, linq, list, enums

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    A,
    Ab,
    Abc,
    Abcd,
    Abcde
}
```

Using LINQ, I want to extract a list from MyEnum that contains all the items of MyEnum except the items Ab and Abc.

Comment: The first google result gave me the answer already. Please show some effort next time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an enum to a list in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c)

Comment: Do you want a list of strings with the names or a list of MyEnums set to all the values?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You did not understand my question body, I know about Enum.GetValues() but it's not what I'm asking. you should show more effort to analyze the questions instead of fast reacting

Comment: @Bob. Thanks for your comment but this is not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var doNotUse = new[] { MyEnum.Ab, MyEnum.Abc };
var enums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>()
    .Where(me => !doNotUse.Contains(me))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum))
               .Where(r=> r != "Abc" && r != "Ab")
               .ToList();
```

For output:

```
foreach(var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Output:

```
A
Abcd
Abcde
```

Comment: @KingKing, my bad, used `GetValues`, instead of GetNames.

Comment: Whats up with the downvotes ?

Comment: Whats up with the upvotes for `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum).Where(r=> r != "ABC").ToList()` ?

Comment: @I4V, I am surprised at this, I used `GetValues` which was wrong, corrected it and still getting downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need linq :

```
    public void test()
    {
        List<MyEnum> list = new List<MyEnum>();

        foreach (MyEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
```