# How to cast Enum with Description attribute to dictionary?

Tags: c#, enums

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c), and preferably using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358606/524861) along with this [answer to get enum attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276348/524861), how is it possible to cast the enum to a dictionary where `Key` is the enum value itself and `Value` is the description attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the `GetAttributeOfType<T>()` extension method you can simply do:

```
var dic = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum))
.Cast<SomeEnum>()
.ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>())
```

If you directly want the Description in the value:

```
var dic = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum))
.Cast<SomeEnum>()
.ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
```