# How to convert enum to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, enumeration

Here is enum;

```
   public enum myEnum{   
    A= 1,
    B= 2,
    C= 3,
    D= 4,
}
```

I need a List contains all except D,
this way its works;

`List<Enum>{myEnum.A, myEnum.B, myEnum.C}`

but of course its extremely ugly. How can directly convert and filter D of this enum

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt asp.net 4.6

Comment: asp.net is not a language its a framework. youre using c#

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt yeah, I edited the title as that

Comment: What do you want to get in your list - names or values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c   Hope, this helps.

Comment: @Henk Holterman why did you re-open this duplicate? Please close it as it was voted by a handful as a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().Where(x => x != MyEnum.D).ToList();
```

Comment: @TyForHelpDude it's not, it's projecting the objects into a new list...

Comment: Yeah I see my expect was List<Enum> with variables of individual enums list, not List<MyEnum>. Anyway I can live with it also Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an enum to a list [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c):

```
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)).Cast<myEnum>().ToList();
```

And to remove `myEnum.D`, simply call the `Remove` method:

```
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)).Cast<myEnum>().ToList().Remove(myEnum.D);
```

As mentioned in the comments, you could also add only the Enums values, which are not `myEnum.D`:

```
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)).Cast<myEnum>().ToList().Where(val => val != myEnum.D);
```

Comment: It's better to use a `where` instead of adding the ones you want to a list and then removing ...

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the values of an enum by calling `Enum.GetValues(type)` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=netframework-4.8)

After getting all the values you can exclude certain values you don't want:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var allValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof (MyEnum))
            .Cast<MyEnum>()
            .Except(new[]{MyEnum.D})
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var val in allValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}
```

This will output:

A
B
C

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hdZmAK