# Enum in C# and foreach

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: How to enumerate an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/c-how-to-enumerate-an-enum)

Hi All,

I have an Enum

```
public enum AttributeType
    {
        TextField = 1, 
        TextArea = 2,
        Date = 4, 
        Boolean = 8
    }
```

I want to foreach this enum and make an object array of it in this format

```
object data = new object[]
{
   // new object[] { 1,"TextField"}
   new object[] { enumValue, enumText}
};
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, this would do it (assuming .NET 3.5):

```
var allValues = (AttributeType[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(AttributeType));

var array = allValues.Select(value => new object[] { value, value.ToString() })
                     .ToArray();
```

or use an anonymous type:

```
var array = allValues.Select(value => { Value = value, Name = value.ToString() })
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: You dont really need that `(AttributeType[])`  :)

Comment: @leppie: You either need that or a call to Cast, given that Enum.GetValues just returns Array.

Comment: Argh, you are right as usual, I was thinking (incorrectly) it would be `IEnumerable<object>` anyways... (oops).