# Can't include enums in for loop, won't iterate using [i] - Creating deck of cards

Tags: c#

/*Hi I was wondering what I need to do to get this for loop to cycle through my enums, as it doesn't take [].I am attempting to create all the cards in a deck of cards.*/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BlackJackGameX
{
    public class Deck
    {

        Random rNumber = new Random();

        List<Card> Cards;
        List<Card> ShuffledDeck;

        public Deck ()
        {
            Cards = NewDeck();
        }

        public void Shuffle()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 51; ++i) 
            {

                int c = rNumber.Next (1, 53);

                ShuffledDeck.Add(Cards[c]);

            }
        }
```

/*This is the main problem area, I think I have made a mistake in my constructer as well but that is probably an unrelated issue*/

```
        private List<Card> NewDeck(Suit CardSuit, FaceValue CardValue, int iValue)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 12; j++) 
                {
                    Card newCard = new Card(CardSuit[i], CardValue[j], iValue[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ShuffledDeck[1].CardValue);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}

/*This is the other class containing the enums*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BlackJackGameX
{

    public enum Suit {Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds}
    public enum FaceValue {Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King}

    public class Card
    {
        public Suit CardSuit;
        public FaceValue CardValue;
        public int iValue;


        public Card (Suit cardSuit, FaceValue cardValue, int ivalue)
        {
            CardSuit = cardSuit;
            CardValue = cardValue;
            iValue =ivalue;
        }

        public Card ()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for you to store each card in a readonly array and predefined them yourself as these cards are constant and will not change. and thus avoiding the loop at all ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an index operator to get an enum value.
see this related post: [Can you loop through all enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/can-you-loop-through-all-enum-values)

plus you have some errors in your cunstroctur,you do not seem to return any lists but you declare that you do. Same goes for the "New Deck" method.

I would suggest the following:

```
private List<Card> NewDeck(Suit CardSuit, FaceValue CardValue, int iValue)
{
   for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
   {
       for (int j = 0; j <= 12; j++) 
       {
           Card newCard = new Card(AllSuit [i], AllFaces[j], iValue[j]);
       }
   }
}

 var AllSuit = new Suit[]
    {
      Suit.Spades,
      Suit.Hearts,
      Suit.Clubs,
      Suit.Diamonds
    };

    //Do the same for AllFaces...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now when I compile I get this error.. "The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration".

Comment: What was the exact code that you have used ? .. try to explicitly declare the array of suits instead of using the var keyword...

Comment: Ok I moved the var into my NewDeck method, as it was inside of the class so that is working, but the problems with my constructor persist, I can't seem to get it to return a List, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will start a new post seeing as this is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross-join:

```
    public enum Suit {Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds}
    public enum FaceValue { Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King }

    public static void Main()
    {

        var cards =
            (from suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)).Cast<Suit>()
             from face in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FaceValue)).Cast<FaceValue>()
             select new { Suit = suit, Face = face })

             .ToList();

        foreach (var card in cards)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", card.Face, card.Suit);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

then in the foreach-loop provided, just read card.Face or card.Suit. Should give you all the cards with all of the suits.