# How to iterate through an enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I want to iterate through an enum so I can call a method with each value of that enum. How can I do that?

```
enum Base { ANC, BTC, DGC };

XmlDocument doc;

doc = vircurex.get_lowest_ask(Base.ANC)
doc = vircurex.get_lowest_ask(Base.BTC)
doc = vircurex.get_lowest_ask(Base.DGC)
```

I want it instead to be something like

```
foreach (var val in values)
   doc = vircurex.get_lowest_ask(....)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The first hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/can-you-loop-through-all-enum-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
foreach(var base in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Base)).Cast<Base>()) 
{
    doc = vircurex.get_lowest_ask(base)
}
```