# Pass arrays of different types of enum values to a function

Tags: c#, arrays, function, enums, parameter-passing

Can someone tell me if it is possible to pass different `Arrays` of `Enum` values to the same function.

Example:

I have two enums:

```
public enum FirstEnum
{ 
    FirstValue, 
    SecondValue
}    

public enum SecondEnum
{ 
    FirstValue, 
    SecondValue
}
```

And I have two Arrays:

```
public FirstEnum[] first = new FirstEnum[]{ FirstEnum.FirstValue,
                                            FirstEnum.FirstValue,
                                            FirstEnum.SecondValue };

public SecondEnum[] second = new SecondEnum[]{SecondEnum.FirstValue,
                                              SecondEnum.SecondValue,
                                              SecondEnum.SecondValue }
```

Now I like to have a function that works with that:

```
public void WorkWithEnums(Enum[] myEnumValues)
{
   // ....    
}
```

and I like to pass my Arrays to this function like that:

```
WorkWithEnums(first);
WorkWithEnums(second);
```

But somehow it doesn't work. Also does not if I try with `object[]` instead of `Enum[]`

Any Ideas?

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: The error that i have is that the call has some invalid arguments.

What i like to do is to figureout that values of the array. I will be also happy with a suggestion how to convert 'first' and 'second' to a string array.

Something like:
'FirstValue'
'FirstValue'
'SecondValue'
but this for both enums.

The goal is to send the values to the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because [covariance is not supported for value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx) (enums are value types).

So you could use:

```
WorkWithEnums(first.Cast<Enum>().ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to make generic method working with "enum T". For example, see answer of this question: [Can you loop through all enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/can-you-loop-through-all-enum-values)

And anyway, primary influencer here is your use-case. What scenario expected inside WorkWithEnums() method?