# Class to fill an array with Cards

Tags: c#

i am busy creating a simple blackjack game in C#.

Now for my cards i want to use an Entity Class "Kaart" because when i want to create other cardgames then Blackjack i can use this again.

So my Objects would consist of : kleur (aces,spades,..) , naam (A,K,J,10,...) and bjvalue (blackjackvalue).

I use this code for this :

```
    class Kaart
{
    public Kaart()
    {
    }


    public Kaart(string kleur, string naam, int bjwaarde)
    {

        this.Kleur = kleur;
        this.Naam = naam;
        this.Bjwaarde = bjwaarde;

    }
    public string Kleur { get; set; } // AutoProperty

    public string Naam { get; set; } // AutoProperty

    public int Bjwaarde { get; set; } // AutoProperty
```

Now my question is :

For use in my game i want to create an array which contains 52 items (0-51), all cards , which represent a full stack of cards.
How should my method be to fill the array with all these objects .. i started like this :

```
public Kaart[] Vulstapel(Kaart[] Stapel) {
```

now the fastest way to add all these values to this array would be?

(the reason why i put them in an array is simple : because i want to be able to copy the array and than delete each card after its already thrown in game)

Comment: Quick suggestion, use a `Queue` instead of an array here. You get ordered removal for free!

Comment: Can you do us non-German guys a favor and translate the code to English? Asking in SOF is one good reason to always write code in English...

Comment: A deck of cards probably deserves to be its own class and not just passed around as an array.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot how do you mean? Isnt it allright to see each card as an object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use enums, as per:
[Can you loop through all enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/can-you-loop-through-all-enum-values)

than iterate over:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
}

enum Suit { Spade = 1, Heart, Diamond, Cross };

public Main()
{
    var values = GetValues<Suit>();
    foreach(var d in values)
    {
        for(int val = 2; val < 11; ++val)
        {
        Kaart k = new Kaart(val,d);
        }
    }
}
```