# How do I get the name of a type argument in a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have a generic method in my class:

```
public static void populateSoapBody<TEnum>(Object obj, string[] aMessage) 
   where TEnum : struct,  IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
```

then I use it to populate the class `obj` from the string array `aMessage` (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168982/generically-populate-different-classes-members) in my other question) ...

Now, for error logging, I'd like to get the name of the type argument that was passed in for the `TEnum` type parameter. For example:

```
private enum DCSSCutomerUpdate_V3
{
       ...
}
```

so, when I call the method like this:

```
Common.populateSoapBody<DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3>(wsSoapBody, aMessage);
```

in that method, I want to be able to get `DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3` as a string

Comment: Whats wrong with `typeof(TEnum).FullName`?

Comment: And what is the use of `<TEnum>` if you don't use it in any parameters

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: That's the name of the type; I believe the OP wants the name of the actual constant.

Comment: @EricLippert Can you actually call it as `populateSoapBody<SomeEnum.Member>()`? That seems like an awful abuse of generics

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: No, you can't do that. I think the OP is trying to say that parameter "obj" is a value of type TEnum. The question is confusing.

Comment: @EZI: I use it to define the members of the class to be populated, and the index of the string array which as the data that needs to go into the class

Comment: @EricLippert: yes, I want the name of the actual constant

Comment: @OurManInBananas But you can use it  as `populateSoapBody<SomeEnum>(anotherEnum,null)` so do you think it is correct?

Comment: This is still really confusing. Could you explain *exactly* what name you are talking about, and what `TEnum` has to do with any of this?

Comment: What is more interesting to me is why the OP asked the question without trying ToString first.

Comment: I want the name of the Enumerated constant defined by `TEnum` so when I call the method using `Common.populateSoapBody<DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3>(wsSoapBody, aMessage);` I can get the string `DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3`

Comment: In this case you should look at the @BradleyDotNET's answer or more specific `typeof(TEnum).Name`.

Comment: you said to clarify, but you repeated the same thing. you should specify that you want the name of `TEnum`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want the name of the actual constant.

```
obj.ToString()
```

gives you the name of the enumerated element if obj is a boxed instance of an enumerated type. For example:

```
class P
{
  enum E { ABC } 
  static void Main()
  {
     object obj = E.ABC;
     Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); // ABC
  }
}
```

> I want the name of the Enumerated constant that I pass in when calling it. So, defined by `TEnum` so when I call the method using `Common.populateSoapBody<DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3>(wsSoapBody, aMessage);` I can get the string `DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3`

That is not a *constant*. You will make it much easier on both yourself and the people trying to help you if you use the right names for things.

`E.ABC` above is a *constant*. `E` is a *type*. In your example `TEnum` is a *type parameter* and the type `DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3` is a *type argument*.

Your question is therefore:

> I have a generic method `M<T>()`; how do I get the name of the type argument supplied for type parameter `T`?

The answer to that is:

```
void M<T>()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
}
```

Comment: sorry Eric, I want the name of the Enumerated constant that I pass in when calling it. So, defined by `TEnum` so when I call the method using `Common.populateSoapBody<DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3>(wsSoapBody, aMessage)`; I can get the string **DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3**

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Yes, you are right, I was blind to the fact that it's a Type .. thanks for explaining I have edited my question to give more information

Comment: Thank you for your explanation - I guess coming from VB6 and learning c# on the job I haven't really got a decent grounding in types yet...

Answer (score 5):

To get the name of the *type* `TEnum`, just use:

```
typeof(TEnum).Name
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that its an enum, and is not a "Enumerated constant", so I think you have some terminology wrong here as well.

Comment: it's defined as an Enum in the calling class like this: `private enum DCSSCustomerUpdate_V3
  {
   InstId = 8,`

Comment: @OurManInBananas That doesn't mean that the code here has **anything** to do with that. See Eric's answer as to the correct terminology here.