# Print weekdays from enum

Tags: c#

Being new to programming my question might seem a little basic one, what I want to is to print all the days mentioned in the enum using a loop or otherwise. 
I have used a console application for the same. Tips to improve basics of C# language coding capabilities along with the answer will be much appreciated.

```
using System;

namespace _28_11_2016_enum
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        weekdays wd = weekdays.mon;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {


            int a = (int)wd;
            a = a + i;
            wd = (wd)a;// faulty code.
            Console.WriteLine(wd);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
    enum weekdays : int
    {
        mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sun
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/can-you-loop-through-all-enum-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to loop - `Enum.GetNames` returns the names, and `string.Join` concat them together into a single `string`:

```
 // mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sun
 Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(weekdays))));
```

in case you want `int` values:

```
 // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
 Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Enum.GetValues(typeof(weekdays)).Cast<int>()));
```

**Edit**: if you insist on loop I suggest *foreach* one:

```
 // mon == 0 ... sun == 6
 foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(weekdays))) {
   Console.WriteLine($"{item} == {(int) item}"); 
 }
```

In case of *for* loop

```
 // do not use magic numbers - 0..7 but actual values weekdays.mon..weekdays.sun 
 for (weekdays item = weekdays.mon; item <= weekdays.sun; ++item) {
   Console.WriteLine($"{item} == {(int) item}"); 
 }
```

However, in real world applications, please, use standard [DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) `enum`.

**Edit 2**: your own code (*in the question*) improved:

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) { // do not use magic numbers: what does, say, 5 stand for?
     // we want weekdays, not int to be printed out
     weekdays wd = (weekdays) i;

     Console.WriteLine(wd);
   }

   Console.Read();
 }
```

**Edit 3**: your own code (*in the answer*) improved:

```
 // you have to do it just once, that's why pull the line off the loop 
 string[] s = Enum.GetNames(typeof(weekdays));

 // do not use magic numbers - 7: what does "7" stands for? - 
 // but actual value: s.Length - we want to print out all the items
 // of "s", i.e. from 0 up to s.Length    
 for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
```

Comment: Wonderful, I love your answer. But as I am learning to code, I am trying to mess up with looping. Please can you help me get the answer through looping also?

Comment: I like your slick coding style but I am quite new to coding and am pretty much getting overwhelmed by the above code. If you don't mind can you somehow get down to my level for sometime and improve my code itself so that I am able to follow through easily.

Comment: You are a genius! I have the required output. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have reworked the first code snippet using loops, plz check and comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40316810/7045194

Answer (score 1):

```
wd = (wd)a;// faulty code.
```

The syntax of a cast is `(Type)variable`. So it should be

```
wd = (weekdays)a;
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me but I am not yet getting the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
foreach (var weekDay in Enum.GetNames(typeof(weekDays)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(weekDay);
}
```

While we're at it, let me give you a few tips for naming/style conventions in C#.

`enum`'s name should be using PascalCase:

```
enum WeekDays : int
```

Also in general you want to call your `enum` with a singular form:

```
enum WeekDay : int
```

Deriving from `int` is also superfluous:

```
enum WeekDay
```

`enum` member names should also be written with PascalCase. To increase readability, you may want to use full names instead of shorthands and write them in separate lines:

```
enum WeekDay
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

Of course, if you decide to follow these, then the first snippet becomes:

```
foreach (var weekDay in Enum.GetNames(typeof(WeekDay)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(weekDay);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the naming and style conventions used in C#. It is very helpful indeed.

Comment: No problem. For further reference, you might want to check out [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

I have reworked the first code snippet using loops as shown by [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40307104/7045194)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {

            string[]s = Enum.GetNames(typeof(weekdays));
            Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
        }
```

Comment: push `string[]s = Enum.GetNames(typeof(weekdays));` off the loop and do not use *magic numbers*, but `s.Length` instead: `string[] s = Enum.GetNames(typeof(weekdays)); for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i) Console.WriteLine(s[i]);`