# Looping through enums for camera modes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I have a simple `enum` value type for 3 camera modes. I know how to print out each value (e.g. `Debug.Log(OrbitStyle.Smooth)` or `Debug.Log(OrbitStyle.Smooth.ToString())`) but in order to print them all out, I thought I had to write a function for it.

My **first** question is: Is this the only way to do so, or is there a function for looping through `enum`s?

My **second** question is: Why does my `Unity3D` program crashes when I add `=` to include all values, while incrementing/decrementing? The program below prints out `Smooth, Step` and then `Fade, Step` but I use `<=` or `>=` to include the least and highest values as well, but it always crashes. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class CameraOribit : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum OrbitStyle
    {
        Smooth,
        Step,
        Fade
    }


    void Start()
    {
        for ( OrbitStyle e1 = OrbitStyle.Smooth; e1 < OrbitStyle.Fade; e1 = IncrementEnum(e1) )
        {
            Debug.Log(e1);
        }

        for ( OrbitStyle e2 = OrbitStyle.Fade; e2 > OrbitStyle.Smooth; e2 = DecrementEnum(e2) )
        {
            Debug.Log(e2);
        }
    }


    static OrbitStyle IncrementEnum(OrbitStyle e)
    {
        if (e == OrbitStyle.Fade)
            return e;
        else
            return e + 1;
    }

    static OrbitStyle DecrementEnum(OrbitStyle e)
    {
        if (e == OrbitStyle.Smooth)
            return e;
        else
            return e - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you can see the answer here: [Can you loop through all enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/can-you-loop-through-all-enum-values)

For your second question, the nature of a `for` loop is:

```
for (OrbitStyle e1 = OrbitStyle.Smooth; e1 <= OrbitStyle.Fade; e1 = IncrementEnum(e1)) {
  Debug.Log(e1);
}
```

Equal:

```
OrbitStyle e1 = OrbitStyle.Smooth;
while(e1 <= OrbitStyle.Fade){
    Debug.Log(e1);
    e1 = IncrementEnum(e1);
}
```

Now, as you can see, at the end of the loop (when `e1 == OrbitStyle.Fade`), the condition return true so the code run, and at the end, when `IncrementEnum(e1)` is called once more, e1 is already at the maximum number of the enum, and trying to increase it again result in a crash.