# Convert a flagged enum to another one

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I have a general enum, let's say G that has some flagged values (One = 0 / Two = 1 / Three = 2 / Four = 4 / Five = 8, and so on).

I then have another enum (let's say B) that "extends" G with this kind of pattern : One = G.One / Two = G.Two / Three = G.Three / Four = G.Four (and that's all, no Five in this one).

I finally have have a last enum (let's say C) that also "extends" G with the same pattern type but other values : Three = G.Three / Four = G.Four / Five = G.Five (no One and Two in this one).

I'd like to find a generic function to convert B into C or C into B.
For example, if I have "A valsAsA = A.One | A.Three | A.Four", I'd like a function like this : "B valsAsB = convert(valsAsA);" that would gives me "B.Three | A.Four".

This should be really generic because I have not only A and B enums, but also C, D, E... with different possible enum values, but always values from the generic enum.

Is it possible without checking all possibilities and adapting the function each time I add a new enum ?

An example:

```
    public enum General : int
    {
        One = 0,
        Two = 1,
        Three = 2,
        Four = 4,
        Five = 8
    }

    public enum A : int
    {
        One = General.One,
        Two = General.Two,
        Three = General.Three,
        Four = General.Four,
    }

    public enum B : int
    {
        Three = General.Three,
        Four = General.Four,
        Five = General.Five
    }

    public enum C : int
    {
        One = General.One,
        Three = General.Three,
        Five = General.Five
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void testConvert()
        {
            A valAsA = A.One | A.Three | A.Four;
            B valAsB = convertFct(valAsA); // Should give me "B.Three | B.Four"
            C valAsC = convertFct(valAsA); // Should give me "C.One | C.Three"
        }
    }
```

I tested that :

```
A valAsA = A.One | A.Three | A.Four; 
C valAsC = (C)valAsA;
C valAsCReal = C.One | C.Three; // expected result
```

with no luck.. valAsC = 6 while valAsCReal = 2...

Thank you very much

Comment: Note: should be good to have only one function with a generic return has i'd like not to create a new function each time I add a new enum.

Comment: This sounds like a [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What do you want to achieve with that? You can easily cast from one enum to another like `valsAsB = (B)valsAsA;`

Comment: You know that there is no such thing as enum inheritance and `A valsAsA = (A)1025;` is still a valid `A` value, right?

Comment: Depending on your scenario, you may be doing things here with enums that are better served with `BitArray` and masks (or less geekily, a `HashSet` of more meaningful values that you can union and intersect). Enums tend to be overused especially in "dynamic" scenarios, where what you've got isn't actually a statically safe-at-compile-time enum, which is more or less the intended use.

Comment: See an example in my "answer"

Comment: @JeroenMostert , The application I'm working on is as it, I can't change everything... :/

Comment: they are all the same (literally). Check this: `var a = A.One | A.Two; var r = a.HasFlag(StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: I tested that :
```
A valAsA = A.One | A.Three | A.Four;
C valAsC = (C)valAsA;
C valAsCReal = C.One | C.Three;
```
with no chance.. valAsC = 6 while valAsCReal = 2...

The HasFlag function returns a boolean and don't take this kind of argument..

Comment: @PP_RhuM Take a look at [Enum.ToObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/k6x6b517(v%3Dvs.95)).

Comment: Thank you @AlessandroD'Andria , but not working as expected.
Enum.ToObject(typeof(C), valAsA) == 6 but 
2 or "C.Three" is expected in my example... :'(

Comment: Don't understand what you're trying to do here, you explicitly set `valAsA` to *three* flags, but `valAsCReal` only to *two* of them, of course they're going to have different values. You're missing the extra 4 from `A.Four` (or the equivalent in `C` which you don't have). You need to clarify *why* you expected them to be equal.

Comment: valsAsA = 0 | 2 | 4 = 6. valsAsC doesn't have the "4" bit flag (Four), so converting valAsA to a C enum should gives me 0 | 2 = 2, but when casting, it gives me 6... anyway, I could get a solution (see answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with generics is a little tricky because it is not possible to set up a type constraint that allows enumerations in general (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)). The best you can do is constraint to `struct, IConvertible` and do a runtime check, as I do in this example.

If you can cope with that part of the ugliness, the rest is fairly simple:

First, write two methods to convert to and from a `General`. Since your enums are bit masks, the "conversion" is actually just a binary `and` operation against the sum of all possible values, which you can obtain using [GetValues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/how-to-loop-through-all-enum-values-in-c).

Once you have performed the and operation, you can return an enum of the appropriate type by converting the integer using [Enum.ToObject()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum-in-c-sharp).

```
static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public General ToGeneral<T>(this T input) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("Input must be an enum.");

        return (General)((int)(object)input & Enum.GetValues(typeof(General)).Cast<int>().Sum());
    }

    static public T ToEnum<T>(this General input)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("Output type must be an enum.");

        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), (int)input & Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>().Sum());
    }
}
```

Once those are written, conversion to and from any enum is easy:

```
static public TOut Convert<TIn,TOut>(TIn input) where TIn : struct, IConvertible where TOut: struct, IConvertible
{
    var general = input.ToGeneral();
    return general.ToEnum<TOut>();
}
```

Test code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    A valAsA = A.One | A.Three | A.Four;
    B valAsB = Convert<A, B>(valAsA);  // Should give me "B.Three | B.Four"
    C valAsC = Convert<A, C>(valAsA); // Should give me "C.One | C.Three"

    Console.WriteLine("{0} should equal {1}", valAsB, (B.Three | B.Four));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} should equal {1}", valAsC, (C.One | C.Three));
}
```

Output:

```
6 should equal 6
Three should equal Three
```

[See the code in action at DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PtahSw)

Comment: Really elegant solution !! thank you very much. Using my code, I don't need to do the "ToGeneral" function because I'm sure that I can cast A, B or C to General simply using "(General)valAsA" for example and I have in fact many "General" enums (real name: MassOptions / PowerOptions / ThermalOptions ...) so I'd need to create a function for all these. I will adapt my own solution with Linq as you did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Damn !!! I could create this incredible function that answer to my question but please... tell me that there is something more elegant... xD

```
        private TRet ConvertIt<TRet, TOrig>(TOrig values) where TOrig : struct, IConvertible where TRet : struct, IConvertible
        {
            if (!typeof(TOrig).IsEnum || 
                !typeof(TRet).IsEnum ||
                !typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TOrig)) || 
                !typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TRet)))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("TOrig and TRet must be an enumerated type extending integer");
            }

            bool retEnumHasZero = false;

            foreach (var flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TRet)))
            {
                if ((int)flag == 0)
                {
                    retEnumHasZero = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!retEnumHasZero)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("TRet enum must have the 0 flag");
            }

            Dictionary<int, Enum> valsOrig = new Dictionary<int, Enum>();

            foreach (var flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TOrig)))
            {
                valsOrig.Add((int)flag, (Enum)flag);
            }

            object valuesAsObject = values;
            var valuesAsEnum = (Enum)valuesAsObject;


            int returnedValue = 0;

            foreach (var flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TRet)))
            {
                int flagAsInt = (int)flag;

                if (valsOrig.ContainsKey(flagAsInt) && valuesAsEnum.HasFlag(valsOrig[flagAsInt]))
                {
                    returnedValue |= flagAsInt;
                }
            }

            return (TRet)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TRet), returnedValue);
        }
```

Using the function :

```
A valAsA = A.One | A.Two | A.Three | A.Four;
C valAsC = ConvertIt<C, A>(valAsA);
```

Edit : This implementation looks better :

```
        private T ConvertIt<T>(Enum values) where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Type to return must be an enumerated type");
            }

            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), 0))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Type to return enum must have the 0 flag");
            }

            int returnedValue = 0;

            foreach (var flag in Enum.GetValues(values.GetType()))
            {
                int flagAsInt = (int)flag;

                if (values.HasFlag((Enum)flag) && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), flagAsInt))
                {
                    returnedValue |= flagAsInt;
                }
            }

            return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), returnedValue);
        }
```

Using the function :

```
A valAsA = A.One | A.Two | A.Three | A.Four;
C valAsC = ConvertIt<C>(valAsA);
```

Finally, with the help of John Wu, here is the final function =>

```
        private T ConvertIt<T>(Enum input) where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Type to return must be an enumerated type");
            }

            return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), (int)(object)input & Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>().Sum());
        }
```