# How to correctly type a LINQ request declared as a class property?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

New to C# (started 2 days ago actually), I have the following class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace MicrosoftReference.Linq
{
    public class DataSets
    {

        public static IEnumerable Deck => from s in Suits() from r in Ranks() select new { Suit = s, Rank = r };

        public static int DeckSize => Suits().Count() * Ranks().Count();

        public static (IEnumerable, IEnumerable) Split()
        {
            return (Deck.Take(DeckSize / 2), startingDeck.Skip(DeckSize / 2));
        }
        static IEnumerable<string> Suits()
        {
            yield return "clubs";
            yield return "diamonds";
            yield return "hearts";
            yield return "spades";
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> Ranks()
        {
            yield return "two";
            yield return "three";
            yield return "four";
            yield return "five";
            yield return "six";
            yield return "seven";
            yield return "eight";
            yield return "nine";
            yield return "ten";
            yield return "jack";
            yield return "queen";
            yield return "king";
            yield return "ace";
        }
    }
}
```

As it is, this code will not compile. In the `Split` method, it is illegal to call `Take` and `Skip` methods because Deck is declared as an `IEnumerable` when it should be an `IEnumerable<T>`.
From what I see from the IDE, the correct type should be `IEnumerable<{string, string}>` but this syntax is illegal. This is however what the IDE is telling me when I try another syntax:

> Cannot convert expression type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<{string Suit, string Rank}>'
> to return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

What should I do ?

Comment: Why not make an actual type for Suit and Rank (e.g. "Card"), rather than using an anonymous type, and then use an actual `IEnumerable<Card>` rather than the anonymous type?

Comment: `public static readonly string[] Suits = { "clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades" };` is simpler and faster and easier to debug.

Comment: It's a short question with a long answer :) but generally anons are used where you proceess the object more in the same method. They're great as intermediate objects, for example in LINQ, which you may not have used yet. Fun fact: anonymous objects are immutable in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples):

`public static IEnumerable<(string Suit, string Rank)> Deck => from s in Suits() from r in Ranks() select (Suit: s, Rank: r);`

Comment: I already tried, it generates an error:
  CardsDeck.cs(11, 71): [CS0266] Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string Suit, string Rank>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(string Suit, string Rank)>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Note: `(Suit: s, Rank: r)`, not `new {Suit = s, Rank = r}`.

Comment: Thanks !
When would it be suitable to use the anonymous declaration then ?

Answer (score 1):

tymtam answered your question directly, but seeing as you are new I want to offer some recommendations. You seem to come from a python background which is a lot more free flowing. One of the best things about C# is the type system, and the way you're doing things you pretty much lose all benefits of having it.

Other situations this might not apply, but if you're modelling a standard deck of cards and only a standard deck of cards, you know the suits and ranks wont ever change. This is the perfect situation for [enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) instead of strings. There are ways to enumerate over all the [enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/how-to-loop-through-all-enum-values-in-c) to do a similar thing that you are currently doing.

Secondly, you have 2 concepts that can be perfectly encapsulated in classes. You have a `Card` and you have a `Deck`. If you use enums you can model the `Card` like this:

```
public class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; init; }
    public Rank Rank { get; init; }
}
```

Or you could even use the new [record](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/) type:

```
public record Card(Suit Suit, Rank Rank);
```

The same would then be done for `Deck`

```
public class Deck
{
    public IEnumerable<Card> Cards { get; }
}
```

If you model it this way you could set your `Deck` type up to have the `Split` method on it rather than using `static` methods.

```
public class Deck
{
    private int DeckSize => this.Cards.Count();
    public IEnumerable<Card> Cards { get; }

    public (IEnumerable<Card>, IEnumerable<Card>) Split()
    {
        return (this.Cards.Take(this.DeckSize / 2), this.Cards.Skip(this.DeckSize / 2));
    }
}
```

Better yet, you could return 2 new `Deck`'s instead of `IEnumerable<Card>`. That way you could split each of those returned `Deck`'s again.

As another note, I'd recommend against using that style of `linq` and instead opt for learning the [method/fluent syntax](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-method-syntax). At least in my personal experience not many developers are familiar with the `Query` syntax and will use the `Method` syntax instead. It's also normal C# instead of a special syntax, so it should be simpler to understand.

Comment: Thank you for all the details ! I do have a Python background and I feel like C# is currently trying to import some of the functional approach developed by it in its own way

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to convince your project leader to change property `Deck` such that it returns a proper sequence of Decks

```
class PlayCard // TODO: invent proper name
{
    public string Suit {get; set;}
    public string Rank {get; set;}
}

public static IEnumerable<PlayCard> Deck => from s in ... select new PlayCard
{
    Suit = ...
    Rank = ...
})
```

Or when using method syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<PlayCard> Deck => this.Suits.SelectMany(suit => this.Ranks,
(suit, rank) => new PlayCard
{
    Suit = suit,
    Rank = rand,
});
```

If you really are not allowed to change the return value of property Deck, then officially you can't be certain what the sequence of this return value contains. The only thing that is guaranteed is that it is a sequence of objects.

However, if you are still certain that property Deck contains a sequence of PlayCards, consider to create a procedure that converts objects to PlayCards

```
public PlayCard ToPlayCard(object obj)
{
    ...
}
```

For this you need to read about reflection: `Object.GetType()`, and `Type.GetProperty`.
This is not very efficient.

```
IEnumerable<PlayCard> playCards = Deck.Select(obj => ToPlayCard(obj);
```

Be aware though, that this procedure won't work anymore after the slightest change of the return value of property Deck. Another reason to always use generic classes when returning values to the outside world

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do and what I would do too. However I am just doing the C# reference tutorials at the moment. And this is a good opportunity to run into special cases and ask questions about them.