Unable to Update Enum Property in Entity
I am having trouble updating the enum property in my Question entity. Below are the relevant parts of my code and error message:

The tag helper 'option' must not have C# in the element's attribute
declaration area.

Question.cs:
using quiz.Entities;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class Question
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Question's Text")]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public enum DifficultyLevel
    {
        Easy,
        Medium,
        Hard
    }

    [DisplayName("Zorluk Derecesi")]
    public DifficultyLevel Difficulty { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Şık A")]
    public string AnswerA { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Şık B")]
    public string AnswerB { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Şık C")]
    public string AnswerC { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Şık D")]
    public string AnswerD { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Doğru Şık")]
    public char CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Movie Name (MovieId)")]
    public Guid MovieId { get; set; }

    public virtual Movie? Movie { get; set; }
}

Edit.cshtml:
<div class="form-group mb-4">
 <label asp-for="Difficulty" class="form-label font-weight-bold">Zorluk Derecesi</label>
 <select asp-for="Difficulty" class="form-control bg-secondary text-light border-0 shadow-sm">
     <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
     @foreach (var level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Question.DifficultyLevel)))
     {
         <option value="@level.ToString()" @(Model.Difficulty == level ? "selected" : "")>@level</option>
     }
 </select>
 <span asp-validation-for="Difficulty" class="text-danger"></span>


Does it work if you cast the level to DifficultyLevel in the loop?
(Question.DifficultyLevel[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Question.DifficultyLevel))
https://stackoverflow.com/a/972323/10074443

Thanks for your answer but it didn't work.

The error occurred because I used an incorrect cast while trying to display enum values in a dropdown in the Razor view. Since Enum.GetValues can't be directly used as an array, it needed to be cast to DifficultyLevel with Cast<T>(). The incorrect expression wasn't understood by Razor, resulting in an error.
In Edit.cshtml, I replaced the form in which I perform Enum operations with the following form:
 <div class="form-group mb-4">
      <label asp-for="Difficulty" class="form-label font-weight-bold">Zorluk Derecesi</label>
      <select asp-for="Difficulty" class="form-control bg-secondary text-light border-0 shadow-sm">
          <option value="">Seçiniz</option>
          @foreach (var level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Question.DifficultyLevel)).Cast<Question.DifficultyLevel>())
          {
              <option value="@level">@level</option>
          }
      </select>
      <span asp-validation-for="Difficulty" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>


Glad to know that you have found the solution to solve the issue. You can accept this answer now. This will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.
