# How to find out all possible values of an enum?

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enumerate an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum)

Say I have an enum type MyEnum.  Is there a way in C# to get a list of all possible values for an enum of type MyEnum?

Comment: And of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/c-how-to-enumerate-an-enum

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An instance of the enum can have any assignable to the underlying type (i.e., `int.MinValue` through `int.MaxValue` for any regular enum). You can get a list of the *named* values by calling `Enum.GetNames` and `Enum.GetValues`.

Answer (score 15):

[Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

`Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum));`

will return an array with all the values. I do not know if this helps you.