# How to loop through the ChartColorPalette properties and add to list?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enumerate an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum)

I am using the Microsoft Chart Controls for .NET 3.5 (C#) and have a chart in a winform.

My hope is to allow the user to change the color palette based on their preference.

How do I iterate through the color properties of the ChartColorPalette and add them to a combobox list?

I know it should be something like:

```
for each(something in ChartColorPalette)
{
  combobox.items.add(something.ToString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the names in your enum via the GetNames class method...

```
foreach(string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(ChartColorPalette))
{
}
```

then later if you need the enum for the name you can parse the name value...

```
var val = (ChartColorPalette)Enum.Parse(typeof(ChartColorPalette),"theValue");
```

Comment: At least when you correct the typos ;-)

Answer (score 2):

See [how to enumerate an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/c-how-to-enumerate-an-enum).