# Iteration on enum?

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: How to enumerate an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/c-how-to-enumerate-an-enum)

Hi all I want to know that suppose I define a enum like

```
enum color
{
    red=4;
    blue=5;
    gray=6;
    green=8;
}
```

so can we print value of constant with the help of for loop, i means can we control it by loop;
another question can we integrate it with dropdown list like as array. i means when we declare a  element in side array suppose  i write  same color element,  and those elment we can add with list or dropdown list(simple word binding with control)in asp.net , same thing can we perform with enum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Enum.GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
Color[] colors = (Color[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color));
```

I suspect that may have answered all your questions, but I didn't really follow the second half. If you still need help, please edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: Surely if he's storing his colours as, for example, 4 for red (as opposed to the correct number representation of red) this method wouldn't work?

Comment: @Blam: I don't follow you, I'm afraid.

Comment: can you clearify your ansewer sir i means your comment on 2nd question ?

Comment: foreach (int i in  Enum.GetValue(typeof(color))){ console.writline(i);} it will print 4,5,6,8 what's problem  in it..i am confused from your comment can you clearify your thoughts sir.

Comment: @Nishant: You're implicitly casting to `int` there - if you change the variable to be of type `Color` instead, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Use the static Enum.GetValues() method:

```
foreach (color value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(color)))
{
  //Do something here
}
```

Comment: Clean and nice with one exception "color" type should be "Color". :P