# Enum to Dictionary<int, string> in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, enums

I have searched this online, but I can't find the answer I am looking for.

Basically I have the following enum:

```
public enum typFoo : int
{
   itemA : 1,
   itemB : 2
   itemC : 3
}
```

How can I convert this enum to Dictionary so that it stores in the following Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<int,string> myDic = new Dictionary<int,string>();
```

And myDic would look like this:

```
1, itemA
2, itemB
3, itemC
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place?  I cannot help but wonder if there isn't a better way to solve whatever problem you are using this dictionary for.

Comment: @juharr 26 other people find it useful so far - do you see it yet? I need to pass it down to the UI layer so I can basically use the enum in javascript (in a dropdown) without hardcoding the values.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

See: *[How do I enumerate an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum-in-c)*

```
foreach( typFoo foo in Enum.GetValues(typeof(typFoo)) )
{
    mydic.Add((int)foo, foo.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Careful with any answer using `Enum.GetValues` if there is a chance that multiple enum entries have the same value. Understandably this case is an ant-pattern, but it will cause an exception/problem.

Comment: If you don't know the type, an alternative way of doing this (still prone to the same multiple enum entries issue), given `Type tFoo = typeof(typFoo)` is `Enum.GetNames(tFoo).ToDictionary(t => (int)System.Enum.Parse(tFoo, t), t => t)`

Answer (score 213):

Try:

```
var dict = Enum.GetValues(typeof(fooEnumType))
               .Cast<fooEnumType>()
               .ToDictionary(t => (int)t, t => t.ToString() );
```

Comment: I knew `Enum.ToString()` had something to do with it :)

Comment: +1 This is actually the most direct answer for the problem. I've seen approaches with method extension and reflection, but unecessary if you can accomplish that with linq.

Comment: I'm trying to translate this to VB.net, but I seem to be having trouble with the `.Cast<typFoo>()` line. I tried `.Cast(Of typeFoo)` but am getting an invalid cast exception.

Comment: Fixed it! I was trying to use `Enum.GetNames()` instead of `Enum.GetValues()`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 20):

Adapting [Ani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5583781) so that it can be used as a generic method (thanks, [toddmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583717/enum-to-dictionary-c-sharp/28113615?noredirect=1#comment74967429_28113615)):

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> EnumDictionary<T>()
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enum");
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<T>()
        .ToDictionary(t => (int)(object)t, t => t.ToString());
}
```

Comment: could you just do `(int)(object)t` instead of `(int)Convert.ChangeType(t, t.GetType())`? It compiles. `ChangeType` returns an `object`, so I think your boxing either way.

Comment: Well, as long as your underlying type is `int`. If it's `short`, for example, this wouldn't work. (But then your Dictionary should be modified to return a `short` anyways.)

Comment: You can see my answer below on how I solved that if you're interested.

Answer (score 7):

- Extension method
- Conventional naming
- One line
- C# 7 return syntax (but you can use brackets in those old legacy versions of C#)
- Throws an `ArgumentException` if the type is not `System.Enum`, thanks to `Enum.GetValues`
- IntelliSense will be limited to structs (no `enum` constraint is available yet)
- Allows you to use enum to index into the dictionary, if desired.

```
public static Dictionary<T, string> ToDictionary<T>() where T : struct
  => Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToDictionary(e => e, e => e.ToString());
```

Answer (score 6):

Another extension method that builds on [Arithmomaniac's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583717/enum-to-dictionary-in-c-sharp/28113615#28113615):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a Dictionary&lt;int, string&gt; of the parent enumeration. Note that the extension method must
    /// be called with one of the enumeration values, it does not matter which one is used.
    /// Sample call: var myDictionary = StringComparison.Ordinal.ToDictionary().
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enumValue">An enumeration value (e.g. StringComparison.Ordinal).</param>
    /// <returns>Dictionary with Key = enumeration numbers and Value = associated text.</returns>
    public static Dictionary<int, string> ToDictionary(this Enum enumValue)
    {
        var enumType = enumValue.GetType();
        return Enum.GetValues(enumType)
            .Cast<Enum>()
            .ToDictionary(t => (int)(object)t, t => t.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate over the enum descriptors:

```
Dictionary<int, string> enumDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach(var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(typFoo))
{
    enumDictionary.Add((int)((typFoo)Enum.Parse(typeof(typFoo)), name), name);
}
```

That should put the value of each item and the name into your dictionary.

Comment: This is the only answer that handles cases where multiple enum entries have the same value. Maybe that is an anti-pattern but this can at least help identify the case, rather than returning duplicate entries,

Answer (score 3):

### +1 to [Ani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5583781). Here's the VB.NET version

Here's the VB.NET version of Ani's answer:

```
Public Enum typFoo
    itemA = 1
    itemB = 2
    itemC = 3
End Enum

Sub example()

    Dim dict As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(typFoo)) _
                                                 .Cast(Of typFoo)() _
                                                 .ToDictionary(Function(t) Integer.Parse(t), Function(t) t.ToString())
    For Each i As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String) In dict
        MsgBox(String.Format("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", i.Key, i.Value))
    Next

End Sub
```

---

### Additional example

In my case, I wanted to save the path of important directories and store them in my `web.config` file's AppSettings section. Then I created an enum to represent the keys for these AppSettings...but my front-end engineer needed access to these locations in our external JavaScript files. So, I created the following code-block and placed it in our primary master page. Now, each new Enum item will auto-create a corresponding JavaScript variable. Here's my code block:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rootDirectory = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/")%>';
        // This next part will loop through the public enumeration of App_Directory and create a corresponding JavaScript variable that contains the directory URL from the web.config.
        <% Dim App_Directories As Dictionary(Of String, App_Directory) = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(App_Directory)) _
                                                                   .Cast(Of App_Directory)() _
                                                                   .ToDictionary(Of String)(Function(dir) dir.ToString)%>
        <% For Each i As KeyValuePair(Of String, App_Directory) In App_Directories%>
            <% Response.Write(String.Format("var {0} = '{1}';", i.Key, ResolveUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(i.Value))))%>
        <% next i %>
    </script>
```

*NOTE: In this example, I used the name of the enum as the key (not the int value).*

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static IDictionary<int, string> ConvertToDictionary<T>() where T : struct
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            int key = (int) value;

            dictionary.Add(key, value.ToString());
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public enum typFoo : int
{
   itemA = 1,
   itemB = 2,
   itemC = 3
}

var mydic = EnumHelper.ConvertToDictionary<typFoo>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection:

```
Dictionary<int,string> mydic = new Dictionary<int,string>();

foreach (FieldInfo fi in typeof(typFoo).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
{
    mydic.Add(fi.GetRawConstantValue(), fi.Name);
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most complicated way to do that ;-).

Comment: Ahaha yeah... but it was the only way I knew until now. :D xD :P

Comment: What are the performance implications? Using reflection during serialisation is a *real* performance killer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the name you don't have to create that dictionary at all.

This will convert enum to int:

```
 int pos = (int)typFoo.itemA;
```

This will convert int to enum:

```
  typFoo foo = (typFoo) 1;
```

And this will retrun you the name of it:

```
 ((typFoo) i).toString();
```

Comment: He's not asking how to convert betweeen `int` and `typFoo`.