# Populate dictionary from enum

Tags: linq, dictionary, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum LifeCycle
{
    Pending = 0,
    Approved = 1,
    Rejected = 2,
}
```

And I want to create

```
Dictionary<int, string> LifeCycleDict;
```

from the `enum` value and its `toString`

Is there a way to do it with linq?
(The equivelant to java's enum.values  )
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum to Dictionary c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583717/enum-to-dictionary-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, string> LifeCycleDict = Enum.GetNames(typeof(LifeCycle))
    .ToDictionary(Key => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(LifeCycle), Key), value => value);
```

OR

```
Dictionary<int, string> LifeCycleDict = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LifeCycle)).Cast<int>()
    .ToDictionary(Key => Key, value => ((LifeCycle)value).ToString());
```

OR

```
Dictionary<int, string> LifeCycleDict = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LifeCycle)).Cast<LifeCycle>()
    .ToDictionary(t => (int)t, t => t.ToString());
```

Comment: @rails, The first one using 'Enum.GetNames' and second one using 'Enum.GetValues'