# Code snippets generating a lookup from enum to object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I'd like to generate dictionary lookup code snippet that iterate through existing enums and does a foreach enum print "{ enum.A, "A"},"

Like how the code snippet does 'switch', but my own version of it.

I'm currently using "Snippet Designer" for convenience.

I currently have the following

```
IDictionary<$key$, $value$> _lookup = new Dictionary<$key$, $value$>() 
{
    { $key$, $value$ },
};

$end$
```

Edit: 
Expected result (after filling out the code snippet in the IDE)

```
enum FakeEnum
    {
        Foo, Blah, Bar
    }

    IDictionary<FakeEnum, string> _lookup = new Dictionary<FakeEnum, string>() 
    { 
        {FakeEnum.Foo, string}, 
        {FakeEnum.Blah, string}, 
        {FakeEnum.Bar, string} 
    } ;
```

Comment: Could you post what you think the *final* code should look like? I'm not sure what you are going for, so I can't review the snippet.

Comment: i'm confused - you have a dictionary of enums? can you maybe add an enum to your sample code, to show where you'd see the enums used?

Comment: @PanMan updated my answer to reflect your edited question.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDictionary<$enum$, string> _lookup = new Dictionary<$enum$, string>();

foreach( $enum$ value in Enum.GetValues(typeof($enum$)) )
{
    _lookup .Add(value, value.ToString());
}
$end$
```

(based on [Can you loop through all enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972307/can-you-loop-through-all-enum-values))

---

or try this:

```
var _lookup = Enum.GetValues(typeof($enum$))
               .Cast<$enum$>()
               .ToDictionary(t => t, t => t.ToString() );
$end$
```

based on [Enum to Dictionary c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583717/enum-to-dictionary-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm unsure if you're getting this confused with actual code or not. This code is built for code snippet generation. EG. typing prop, in the IDE will bring up a snippet for you to template your own values into