# How to create list of radio button list using Enum and bind them to model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a two sets of Enums to generate list of radio button list. 1) To generate labels of available features and 2) To generate fix set of values as radio buttons. How to bind such radio button values to model in order to post them to controller? My UI would be something like below:

Available Features:

PublicAPI

```
Enabled  Disabled
```

PrivateAPI

```
Enabled Disabled
```

Authentication

```
Enabled Disabled
```

Below is my model:

```
public enum Features
    {
        PublicAPI = 1,
        PrivateAPI,
        Authentication
    }

public enum FeatureState
    {
        Enabled,
        Disabled,
    }

public class MyModel
{
public Dictionary<Features, FeatureState> FeatureSettings{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you can refer the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583717/enum-to-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

What I have tried , I don't know weather do you want output should look like this or what[image: after debugging]

```
       public enum Features
    {
        PublicAPI = 1,
        PrivateAPI,
        Authentication
    }

    public enum FeatureState
    {
        Enabled,
        Disabled,
    }
    public Dictionary<Features, FeatureState> FeatureSettings { get; set; }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        FeatureSettings = new Dictionary<Features,FeatureState>();
        foreach (Features foo in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Features)))
        {
            FeatureSettings.Add((Features)foo, (FeatureState)foo);
        }

        return View();
    }
```