# Return Key-Value pair list from Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have declared an `enum` as follows:

```
public enum Numbers    {
    One= 1,
    Two
}
```

Now, I need to return the key and value pair of the Enum as an array shown below. How can I do this ?

**Expected Output**

> [{        "1": "One"  },  {       "2": "Two"  } ]

**What I was trying**

This gives the values, but not the key and I need to structure it in to an array.

var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Numbers));

Comment: Note the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583717/enum-to-dictionary-in-c-sharp#comment60307589_5583817) in the linked answer. You may want to group and take the first entry for a given value.