# Creating Dictionary<Enum, int> from Enum

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, enums

As a project I'm creating a poker game.

I have an array of `Cards`, each of which has a value `CardValue` given by the enum below. I want a dictionary `Dictionary<CardValue, int>` to contain the number of occurences of each `CardValue` in the array of `Cards`.

```
public enum CardValue
{
    Ace = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    Jack = 11,
    Queen = 12,
    King = 13
}
```

I have created this dictionary manually, and it only has thirteen key value pairs so wasn't too expensive... but if I had a far larger enum I would want a more efficient way to create this dictionary (from a quick scan of the web you can use `ToDictionary()` for `IEnumarables`, but not sure if relevant).

Note for question similarity: This got flagged for being too similar to:

[Enum to Dictionary<int, string> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583717/enum-to-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

However in this question they had a dictionary of type `Dictionary<int, string>` whereas I want to retain the enum in the key of the dictionary for referencing purposes, and don't want this replaced by an int. E.g. For checking the number of queens that occur in an array of cards I want to check `CardValueCount[CardValue.Queen]` and not `CardValueCount[12]` for readability.

The code I have at the moment is here (edit: removed switch statement as suggested):

```
    public Card[] Cards {get; set;}
    private Dictionary <CardValue, int> CardValueCount
    {
        get
        {
            var cardValueCount = new Dictionary<CardValue, int>()
            {
                { CardValue.Ace, 0},
                { CardValue.Two, 0},
                { CardValue.Three, 0},
                { CardValue.Four, 0},
                { CardValue.Five, 0},
                { CardValue.Six, 0},
                { CardValue.Seven, 0},
                { CardValue.Eight, 0},
                { CardValue.Nine, 0},
                { CardValue.Ten, 0},
                { CardValue.Jack, 0},
                { CardValue.Queen, 0},
                { CardValue.King, 0}
            };
            if (Cards.Length < 1 || Cards == null)
            {
                return cardValueCount;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Card card in Cards)
                {
                    cardValueCount[card.Value]++;
                }
                return cardValueCount;
            }
        }
    }
```

(Edit 2) Removed switch statement as suggested.

Note 1: Haven't actually ran this yet so there may be something that wouldn't work as is!

Comment: A quick note: you could replace your entire `switch` with `cardValueCount[card.Value]++;`

Comment: of course! Should've seen that from the off. Thanks @afarrag !

Comment: You're welcome, buddy. Note also that enum elements are in fact integers. The first enum element is assigned value zero, and each following element is the pervious+1. So, in your example, `CardValue.Ace` is `0` and `CardValue.Two` is `1`, and so on. Hope this helps!

Comment: @afarrag from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum): *"By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type `int`; they start with zero and increase by one following the definition text order. You can explicitly specify any other [integral numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) type as an underlying type of an enumeration type."*

Comment: @afarrag does my updated edit with the enum and the example with the number of occurences of the queen explain why I want the dictionary in this format?

Comment: You can keep the enum (which I blindly assumed its order and value, thanks @TheodorZoulias for correcting me), and use integers at the same time. For instance, initializing your dictionary doesn't have to be this long. You could loop from 1 to 13 and use the loop counter as the dictionary's key.

Answer (score 2):

Resuing the @Theodor's answer.

you could use the GroupBy and Count method in the else part.

```
private Dictionary<CardValue, int> CardValueCount
{
    get
    {
        if (Cards.Length < 1 || Cards == null)
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardValue))
                .Cast<CardValue>()
                .ToDictionary(x => x, x => 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return Cards.GroupBy(card => card.Value)
                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array with all the values of the `CardValue` enumeration, with the static method [`Enum.GetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues).

```
// Retrieves an array of the values of the constants in a specified enumeration.
public static Array GetValues (Type enumType);
```

The array is untyped, so you have to cast each value to `CardValue`.

Usage example:

```
Dictionary<CardValue, int> dict = new();
foreach(CardValue x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardValue)))
    dict.Add(x, 0);
```

...or using LINQ:

```
Dictionary<CardValue, int> dict = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardValue))
    .Cast<CardValue>()
    .ToDictionary(x => x, x => 0);
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JZQ1xm).