# How to enumerate through an enum with arbitrary increments between items

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have an enum with arbitrary increments between contents. Like so:

```
 typedef enum {this=2,that=5,whoa=6}example;
```

Now I want to enumerate through them. If the contents were incremented by 1 for each item, then this would be easy with a simple `for` loop. I could still use a `for` but test for each option in `example` enum before proceeding with an operation, but that seems rather inefficient. Is there a standard way of enumerating through an enum?

Comment: I found the answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum

Comment: That is actually not the answer, at least, if your a looking for a solution in Objective-C (as you tagged). The answer applies for C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enums` are basically integer constants. To simulate sets (I guess, that is what you want) use `dictionaries`. Then, you can easily iterate over all elements.

Comment: i don't think this is entirely true. i have seen examples where methods are used to enumerate through an enum, but that was for sequential ordered enums.

Comment: Of course you *can* do it, but this is nothing but using the fact, that in this case the *set* of numbers is also a *sequence* of numbers. However, this is not true in the general case.

Comment: answer was found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum

Comment: An enum in C# is something quite different than an enum im C. In C#, you have a "real" set type, that you can *convert* to an integer, see e.g., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. In C (and Objective-C derives here from C), an enum is only a special declaration for integer constants.