# How can I enumerate everything in an enum?

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enumerate an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum)

Suppose there is an enum

```
public enum Numbers {one, two, three };
```

What do I have to write instead of the three dots in the following code in order to get output "one", "two", "three":

```
foreach (Numbers n in ...) {
   Console.WriteLine (n.ToString ());
}
```

Of course, I would like to do it in a way such that modifying the enum definition does not require modification of the code within the foreach ( ).

Comment: [How to enumerate an enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
foreach (Numbers n in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Numbers))) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I must convert the Enum.GetValues result to (Numbers []) before the in, then it works. Not very pretty code, but definitely a solution to my problem.

Comment: @JohnB do you need to? It worked out-of-the-box with C# 4.0 in my own programs

Comment: Sorry, no, of course you are right. If I write var n ..., then I must convert.

Comment: @JohnB feel free to write your own static method wrapper to keep your code clean and handle the casting: `public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() { foreach(T value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))) yield return value; }`

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to get the names you can use this:

```
foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Numbers)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Of course if you want to actually use the Enum values, others have pointed out already.

Answer (score 0):

use this: `Enum.GetValues(type)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
        foreach (var n in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Numbers)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
        }
```