# How can I check an array of strings against an Enum and return the highest value that's found?

Tags: c#

I have the following code where the variable userRoles is a string array that can contain and or all of "Super", "Admin", "User" or "Guest".

```
    public static RoleType GetMaxRole()
    {
        var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
        // var maxRole = userRoles.Max();
        if userRoles.Contains("Super")
            return RoleType.Super;
        if userRoles.Contains("Admin")
            return RoleType.Admin;
        if userRoles.Contains("User")
            return RoleType.User;
        if userRoles.Contains("Guest")
            return RoleType.Guest;
        return RoleType.Default;
    }
```

Here is the enum I am using:

```
public enum RoleType
{
    Default = 10,
    Guest = 20,
    User = 30,
    Admin = 40,
    Super = 50
}
```

Is there a way that I could achieve the same without multiple if statements. Some way I could have the userRoles array checked against the Enum?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum

Comment: your GetMaxRole is always just going to return one RoleType, even if there are many roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static RoleType GetMaxRole()
{
    var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
    var maxRole = userRoles.Max(x => (RoleType)Enum.Parse(typeof(RoleType), x));
    return maxRole;
}
```

Comment: you can directly `return userRoles.Max(x => (RoleType)Enum.Parse(typeof(RoleType), x))`