# Trying to populate List w/ Enum but getting 'type' is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#, types, enums

I'm creating a deck of cards and have my Suits and Values in Enums but my syntax is off in trying to populate my List deck.  Also as an aside, the Ace can have a value of 1 or 11, is there some way to incorporate that into my Enum or do I need to just code that in when performing things such as summing a hand for blackjack?

```
public class Deck
{
    private List<Card> cards;
    private Random random = new Random();
    public Deck()
    {
        cards = new List<Card>();
        for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++)
            //for (int v = 0; v < 14; v++)
            foreach(Enum v in Values)
                cards.Add(new Card((Suits)s, (Values)v));
    }
```

And here is my Enums for Suit and Value:

```
public enum Suits
{
    Spades,
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Hearts
}

public enum Values
{
    Ace = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    Jack = 10,
    Queen = 10,
    King = 10
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum)

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is this line:

```
foreach(Enum v in Values)
```

You cannot enumerate `enum`'s in that way. `Values` is the name of your `enum` **type** declaration.. not a group of values.

You can do something like this though:

```
foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Values)))
```

Comment: This worked but now when I print the card names, I get the word "Ten" for all of the face cards.  Here is my pertinent Card class info:  public class Card
    {
        public Suits suit { get; set; }
        public Values value { get; set; }

        public Card(Suits _suit, Values _value)
        {
            this.suit = _suit;
            this.value = _value;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return value.ToString() + " of " + suit.ToString(); }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }

Comment: value.ToString() works for Ace, Two, etc. but all the face cards show up as "Ten"

Comment: This is because they all have the same value. `Ten`, `Jack`, `Queen` and `King` are all the same at a low level. They all equal 10. You won't be able to tell them apart.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Enum.GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) to get an array of all the values for an enum.

Then you should be able to do something like this (not sure if this will compile, but you should get the idea):

```
foreach (var suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suits)))
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Values)))
    {
        cards.Add(new Card((Suits)suit, (Values)value));
    } 
}
```

I don't think your enum for values will work properly though. Once you have initialised something with one of the values between `Ten` to `King`, you will be unable to tell what it was originally.

I think you need something more like this (also rename your pluralised enum names to be singular, to match normal naming conventions):

```
public enum Suit
{
    Spades,
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Hearts
}

public enum Rank
{
    Ace   = 1,
    Two   = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four  = 4,
    Five  = 5,
    Six   = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine  = 9,
    Ten   = 10,
    Jack  = 11,
    Queen = 12,
    King  = 13
}

class Card
{
    readonly Suit _suit;
    readonly Rank _rank;

    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank)
    {
        _suit = suit;
        _rank = rank;
    }

    public Rank Rank
    {
        get
        {
            return _rank;
        }
    }

    public Suit Suit
    {
        get
        {
            return _suit;
        }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (Rank >= Rank.Ten)
            {
                return 10;
            }
            else
            {
                return (int) Rank;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _rank + " of " + _suit + " with value " + Value;
    }
}
```

You could also use Linq to initialise your `Card` list as follows:

```
List<Card> cards = 
(
    from suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)).OfType<Suit>()
    from rank in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Rank)).OfType<Rank>()
    select new Card(suit, rank)
).ToList();
```

If you want to keep the `Value` calculation more tightly associated with `Rank` rather than doing it in `Card`, you can write an extension method for `Rank`:

```
static class RankExt
{
    public static int Value(this Rank rank)
    {
        if (rank >= Rank.Ten)
        {
            return 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return (int)rank;
        }
    }
}
```

Then wherever you have a `Rank` you can use `Rank.Value()`, e.g. Card's `ToString()` would become:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return _rank + " of " + _suit + " with value " + _rank.Value();
}
```