# Can't get the enum value out

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following piece of code :

```
private List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> _list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

public MyclassConstructor()
{
    foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle)))
        _list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>((int)value, value.ToString()));
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the int part of this enum as the key... pretty dumb question I'm sure but I can't get it working.

I was refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum) article up here on stackoverflow but as you can see this doesn't work

So how can I get the int value of the enum?

Edit : When I try to compile I got the following error message "Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'"

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear: *what* isn't working in the code above? Also, could you make the KeyValuePair's key type `FontStyle` instead of `int`?

Comment: Casting the value as an int should take care of it.  Surprised that isn't working.

Comment: @DanJ Sorry, it simply doesn't compile with the error message "Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'". I will edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your loop statement to loop over `FontStyle`, not `Enum`:

```
foreach (FontStyle value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle)))
```

Or using [implicit typed variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) and `var` keyword:

```
foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle)))
```

Comment: This was it... Just fix typo `FontStylevalue` to `FontStyle value` and I will mark as answer as soon as I will be able to do so

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Enum Name from value?yes means, just call Enum.GetName(typeof(yourtype),value).Try to use var Keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var _list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle))
            .Cast<FontStyle>()
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>((int)x, x.ToString()));
```