# Convert Enumeration to an Integer Array With an Extension Method

Tags: vb.net, generics, extension-methods, enumeration

Assumed there is an enumeration:

```
Public Enum MyEnum
    Value1 = 100
    Value2 = 200
    Value3 = 300
End Enum
```

How can an extension method be implemented to get an integer array of all values of this enumeration?

```
Dim ints As Integer() = GetType(MyEnum).ToIntArray()
' result: ints = {100, 200, 300}
```

(I've already seen that the extension method must base on a type.)

Comment: There's some nice extension methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToIntArray(Of T As Type)(a As T) As Integer()
    Return [Enum].GetValues(a).Cast(Of Integer)().ToArray
End Function
```

Comment: I would add a check if the type is an enum `a.IsEnum`.

Comment: @Styxxy: yes thought about this, too. But actually this is implicitely done in `[Enum].GetValues()`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, implicitly.

Comment: I wondered if the **order in the array** would be defined. The answer is yes but surprisingly it is not "as defined." It is (from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx)): _The elements of the array are sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude)._