# Getting all aliased values with Enum.GetValues

Tags: c#, enums

I have an `enum` which has a few aliases:

```
enum {
   A = 0,
   B = 1,
   OtherB = 1,
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to iterate over all values of the enumeration using `Enum.GetValues`. However, I need the string representation of the enum values, not the integer values. Just iterating over `Enum.GetValues`, I get a sequence `A, B, B, ...` (or for some enums `A, OtherB, OtherB, ...`, but regardless I only get one of each value).

Is it possible to get all the "String-values" of an enum, or are they removed during compilation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate an enum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları It is not the duplicate of that question. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: If you need enum string representation you should try with Enum.GetNames(). From name then you can always get the value (if needed) with parsing.

Comment: @Adriano Why didn't you make your comment an answer?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn someone else did it, no need for a dup!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/105421/456814).

Comment: Wow. Anyone want to nominate me for the _Annual RTFM awards_? How did I miss that method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(WhatEverEnum))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
            foreach(var str in Enum.GetNames(typeof(myEnum)))
            {
                // use str
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
```