# Set value to [Flags] Enum from list c#

Tags: c#, enum-flags

I need to set the Enum value by items taken from the list.

I have Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum EnumTest
{
    Val1= 1, 

    Val2= 2, 

    Val3= 4
}
```

List with values:

```
var values = new List<EnumTest> {EnumTest.Val1, EnumTest.Val3};
```

How can I get the following result using a foreach?

```
var result = EnumTest.Val1 | EnumTest.Val3;
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate an enum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: @Nikola Not a duplicate of that. Here, there is a concrete list to iterate over.

Comment: @Nikola Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum-in-c/944352#944352 this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using Linq:

```
var result = values.Aggregate((x, y) => x |= y);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
EnumTest result = 0;

foreach (EnumTest et in values)
{
   result |= et;
}
```