# Return a List<> of active masks in C#

Tags: c#

Here's the code I'm working on (I found some of it online) and I'm trying to return a `List<>` of the flags that are active. Here's the code:

```
public static class BitMask {
        public static bool IsSet<T>(T flags, T flag) where T : struct {
            int flagsValue = (int)(object)flags;
            int flagValue = (int)(object)flag;

            return (flagsValue & flagValue) != 0;
        }

        public static void Set<T>(ref T flags, T flag) where T : struct {
            int flagsValue = (int)(object)flags;
            int flagValue = (int)(object)flag;

            flags = (T)(object)(flagsValue | flagValue);
        }

        public static void Unset<T>(ref T flags, T flag) where T : struct {
            int flagsValue = (int)(object)flags;
            int flagValue = (int)(object)flag;

            flags = (T)(object)(flagsValue & (~flagValue));
        }

        public static List<T> GetActiveMasks<T>(ref T flags) where T : struct {
            List<T> returned = new List<T>();
            foreach(T value in flags) 
                if(IsSet(flags, value))
                    returned.Add(value);

            return returned;
        }
    }
```

However, I'm running into this issue:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'T' because 'T' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' (CS1579) - C:\Users\Christian\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\OblivionScripts\OblivionScripts\Common\BitMask.cs:36,4
```

Could someone please nudge me in the right direction as I'm still new to C#.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/enumerate-an-enum

Comment: enums can be long or unlong, not just int.

Comment: Your code is a very strange way to make this kind of thing generic. If you choose this path anway, use `ulong` to support larger primitives (right now, a 64-bit primitive will have its 32 most significant bits erased using this method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, what is `T` going to be replaced with? Is this supposed to work with an `enum` that has the `[Flags]` attribute?

If so, then you should be able to get the code to work by writing your method like this:

```
    public static List<T> GetActiveMasks<T>(ref T flags) where T : struct {
        List<T> returned = new List<T>();
        foreach(T value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>()) 
            if(IsSet(flags, value))
                returned.Add(value);

        return returned;
    }
```

Now, that said: note that in many such `enum` scenarios, the `enum` type has not only individual flags, but aliases and/or combined flags. Your code will detect those as being "set" as well. There's not enough context in your question to know whether this would actually be a problem, never mind how to address it correctly. I simply mention it as a possible "gotcha", in case you weren't aware.

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) - C:\Users\Christian\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\OblivionScripts\OblivionScripts\Common\BitMask.cs:36,49

Comment: You need to include `using System.Linq;` in your .cs file for the LINQ extensions (like `Cast()`) to work. That said, I include that only as a personal preference for clarity in the code; the `foreach` statement will implicitly cast (if possible) for you, so you could just omit that if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

`flags` needs to be some enumerable type, you probably meant:

```
  public static List<T> GetActiveMasks<T>(ref IEnumerable<T> flags) 
          where T : struct {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `flags` you pass in must be a collection of `T`, because `T` is a `struct` not a collection.

```
  public static List<T> GetActiveMasks<T>(ref IEnumerable<T> flags) where T : struct {
        List<T> returned = new List<T>();
        foreach(T value in flags) 
            if(IsSet(flags, value))
                returned.Add(value);

        return returned;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate on a generic type. If the flags parameter were of type `List<T>` you'd be able to iterate on that.

```
public static List<T> GetActiveMasks<T>(ref List<T> flags) where T : struct
```