# Is there an enumeration for code page

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, enums

I was wondering, why there is no enumeration in C# for the code page.
So who ever comes in this situation I have made my own.
Reference: [Microsoft link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Because this is no funny work, I post it here.
Please feel free to correct if I missed something...

```
public enum CodePage
{
  /// <summary>Default system encoding</summary>
  [Description("Default system encoding")]
  Default = 0,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada)")]
  IBM037 = 37,
  /// <summary>OEM United States</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("OEM United States")]
  IBM437 = 437,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (International)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (International)")]
  IBM500 = 500,
  /// <summary>Arabic (ASMO 708)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Arabic (ASMO 708)")]
  ASMO708 = 708,
  /// <summary>Arabic (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Arabic (DOS)")]
  DOS720 = 720,
  /// <summary>Greek (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Greek (DOS)")]
  Ibm737 = 737,
  /// <summary>Baltic (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Baltic (DOS)")]
  Ibm775 = 775,
  /// <summary>Western European (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Western European (DOS)")]
  Ibm850 = 850,
  /// <summary>Central European (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Central European (DOS)")]
  Ibm852 = 852,
  /// <summary>OEM Cyrillic</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("OEM Cyrillic")]
  IBM855 = 855,
  /// <summary>Turkish (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Turkish (DOS)")]
  Ibm857 = 857,
  /// <summary>OEM Multilingual Latin I</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("OEM Multilingual Latin I")]
  IBM00858 = 858,
  /// <summary>Portuguese (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Portuguese (DOS)")]
  IBM860 = 860,
  /// <summary>Icelandic (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Icelandic (DOS)")]
  Ibm861 = 861,
  /// <summary>Hebrew (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Hebrew (DOS)")]
  DOS862 = 862,
  /// <summary>French Canadian (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("French Canadian (DOS)")]
  IBM863 = 863,
  /// <summary>Arabic (864)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Arabic (864)")]
  IBM864 = 864,
  /// <summary>Nordic (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Nordic (DOS)")]
  IBM865 = 865,
  /// <summary>Cyrillic (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Cyrillic (DOS)")]
  Cp866 = 866,
  /// <summary>Greek, Modern (DOS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Greek, Modern (DOS)")]
  Ibm869 = 869,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Multilingual Latin-2)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Multilingual Latin-2)")]
  IBM870 = 870,
  /// <summary>Thai (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Thai (Windows)")]
  Windows874 = 874,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Greek Modern)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Greek Modern)")]
  Cp875 = 875,
  /// <summary>Japanese (Shift-JIS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Japanese (Shift-JIS)")]
  Shiftjis = 932,
  /// <summary>Chinese Simplified (GB2312)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Simplified (GB2312)")]
  Gb2312 = 936,
  /// <summary>Korean</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Korean")]
  Ksc56011987 = 949,
  /// <summary>Chinese Traditional (Big5)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Traditional (Big5)")]
  Big5 = 950,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Turkish Latin-5)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Turkish Latin-5)")]
  IBM1026 = 1026,
  /// <summary>IBM Latin-1</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM Latin-1")]
  IBM01047 = 1047,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada-Euro)")]
  IBM01140 = 1140,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Germany-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Germany-Euro)")]
  IBM01141 = 1141,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway-Euro)")]
  IBM01142 = 1142,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden-Euro)")]
  IBM01143 = 1143,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Italy-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Italy-Euro)")]
  IBM01144 = 1144,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Spain-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Spain-Euro)")]
  IBM01145 = 1145,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (UK-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (UK-Euro)")]
  IBM01146 = 1146,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (France-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (France-Euro)")]
  IBM01147 = 1147,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (International-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (International-Euro)")]
  IBM01148 = 1148,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic-Euro)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic-Euro)")]
  IBM01149 = 1149,
  /// <summary>Unicode</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Unicode")]
  Utf16 = 1200,
  /// <summary>Unicode (Big endian)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Unicode (Big endian)")]
  UnicodeFFFE = 1201,
  /// <summary>Central European (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Central European (Windows)")]
  Windows1250 = 1250,
  /// <summary>Cyrillic (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Cyrillic (Windows)")]
  Windows1251 = 1251,
  /// <summary>Western European (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Western European (Windows)")]
  Windows1252 = 1252,
  /// <summary>Greek (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Greek (Windows)")]
  Windows1253 = 1253,
  /// <summary>Turkish (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Turkish (Windows)")]
  Windows1254 = 1254,
  /// <summary>Hebrew (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Hebrew (Windows)")]
  Windows1255 = 1255,
  /// <summary>Arabic (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Arabic (Windows)")]
  Windows1256 = 1256,
  /// <summary>Baltic (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Baltic (Windows)")]
  Windows1257 = 1257,
  /// <summary>Vietnamese (Windows)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Vietnamese (Windows)")]
  Windows1258 = 1258,
  /// <summary>Korean (Johab)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Korean (Johab)")]
  Johab = 1361,
  /// <summary>Western European (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Western European (Mac)")]
  Macintosh = 10000,
  /// <summary>Japanese (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Japanese (Mac)")]
  Xmacjapanese = 10001,
  /// <summary>Chinese Traditional (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Traditional (Mac)")]
  Xmacchinesetrad = 10002,
  /// <summary>Korean (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Korean (Mac)")]
  Xmackorean = 10003,
  /// <summary>Arabic (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Arabic (Mac)")]
  Xmacarabic = 10004,
  /// <summary>Hebrew (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Hebrew (Mac)")]
  Xmachebrew = 10005,
  /// <summary>Greek (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Greek (Mac)")]
  Xmacgreek = 10006,
  /// <summary>Cyrillic (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Cyrillic (Mac)")]
  Xmaccyrillic = 10007,
  /// <summary>Chinese Simplified (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Simplified (Mac)")]
  Xmacchinesesimp = 10008,
  /// <summary>Romanian (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Romanian (Mac)")]
  Xmacromanian = 10010,
  /// <summary>Ukrainian (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Ukrainian (Mac)")]
  Xmacukrainian = 10017,
  /// <summary>Thai (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Thai (Mac)")]
  Xmacthai = 10021,
  /// <summary>Central European (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Central European (Mac)")]
  Xmacce = 10029,
  /// <summary>Icelandic (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Icelandic (Mac)")]
  Xmacicelandic = 10079,
  /// <summary>Turkish (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Turkish (Mac)")]
  Xmacturkish = 10081,
  /// <summary>Croatian (Mac)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Croatian (Mac)")]
  Xmaccroatian = 10082,
  /// <summary>Unicode (UTF-32)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Unicode (UTF-32)")]
  Utf32 = 12000,
  /// <summary>Unicode (UTF-32 Big endian)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Unicode (UTF-32 Big endian)")]
  Utf32BE = 12001,
  /// <summary>Chinese Traditional (CNS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Traditional (CNS)")]
  XChineseCNS = 20000,
  /// <summary>TCA Taiwan</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("TCA Taiwan")]
  Xcp20001 = 20001,
  /// <summary>Chinese Traditional (Eten)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Traditional (Eten)")]
  XChineseEten = 20002,
  /// <summary>IBM5550 Taiwan</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM5550 Taiwan")]
  Xcp20003 = 20003,
  /// <summary>TeleText Taiwan</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("TeleText Taiwan")]
  Xcp20004 = 20004,
  /// <summary>Wang Taiwan</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Wang Taiwan")]
  Xcp20005 = 20005,
  /// <summary>Western European (IA5)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Western European (IA5)")]
  XIA5 = 20105,
  /// <summary>German (IA5)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("German (IA5)")]
  XIA5German = 20106,
  /// <summary>Swedish (IA5)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Swedish (IA5)")]
  XIA5Swedish = 20107,
  /// <summary>Norwegian (IA5)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Norwegian (IA5)")]
  XIA5Norwegian = 20108,
  /// <summary>US-ASCII</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("US-ASCII")]
  UsAscii = 20127,
  /// <summary>T.61</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("T.61")]
  Xcp20261 = 20261,
  /// <summary>ISO-6937</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISO-6937")]
  Xcp20269 = 20269,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Germany)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Germany)")]
  IBM273 = 20273,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway)")]
  IBM277 = 20277,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden)")]
  IBM278 = 20278,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Italy)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Italy)")]
  IBM280 = 20280,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Spain)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Spain)")]
  IBM284 = 20284,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (UK)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (UK)")]
  IBM285 = 20285,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Japanese katakana)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Japanese katakana)")]
  IBM290 = 20290,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (France)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (France)")]
  IBM297 = 20297,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Arabic)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Arabic)")]
  IBM420 = 20420,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Greek)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Greek)")]
  IBM423 = 20423,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Hebrew)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Hebrew)")]
  IBM424 = 20424,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Korean Extended)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Korean Extended)")]
  XEBCDICKoreanExtended = 20833,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Thai)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Thai)")]
  IBMThai = 20838,
  /// <summary>Cyrillic (KOI8-R)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Cyrillic (KOI8-R)")]
  Koi8r = 20866,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic)")]
  IBM871 = 20871,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Russian)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Russian)")]
  IBM880 = 20880,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Turkish)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Turkish)")]
  IBM905 = 20905,
  /// <summary>IBM Latin-1</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM Latin-1")]
  IBM00924 = 20924,
  /// <summary>Japanese (JIS 0208-1990 and 0212-1990)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Japanese (JIS 0208-1990 and 0212-1990)")]
  EUCJP_1990 = 20932,
  /// <summary>Chinese Simplified (GB2312-80)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Simplified (GB2312-80)")]
  Xcp20936 = 20936,
  /// <summary>Korean Wansung</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Korean Wansung")]
  Xcp20949 = 20949,
  /// <summary>IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Serbian-Bulgarian)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Serbian-Bulgarian)")]
  Cp1025 = 21025,
  /// <summary>Cyrillic (KOI8-U)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Cyrillic (KOI8-U)")]
  Koi8u = 21866,
  /// <summary>Western European (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Western European (ISO)")]
  Iso88591 = 28591,
  /// <summary>Central European (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Central European (ISO)")]
  Iso88592 = 28592,
  /// <summary>Latin 3 (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Latin 3 (ISO)")]
  Iso88593 = 28593,
  /// <summary>Baltic (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Baltic (ISO)")]
  Iso88594 = 28594,
  /// <summary>Cyrillic (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Cyrillic (ISO)")]
  Iso88595 = 28595,
  /// <summary>Arabic (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Arabic (ISO)")]
  Iso88596 = 28596,
  /// <summary>Greek (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Greek (ISO)")]
  Iso88597 = 28597,
  /// <summary>Hebrew (ISO-Visual)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Hebrew (ISO-Visual)")]
  Iso88598 = 28598,
  /// <summary>Turkish (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Turkish (ISO)")]
  Iso88599 = 28599,
  /// <summary>Estonian (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Estonian (ISO)")]
  Iso885913 = 28603,
  /// <summary>Latin 9 (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Latin 9 (ISO)")]
  Iso885915 = 28605,
  /// <summary>Europa</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Europa")]
  XEuropa = 29001,
  /// <summary>Hebrew (ISO-Logical)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Hebrew (ISO-Logical)")]
  Iso88598i = 38598,
  /// <summary>Japanese (JIS)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Japanese (JIS)")]
  Iso2022jp = 50220,
  /// <summary>Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana)")]
  CsISO2022JP = 50221,
  /// <summary>Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana - SO/SI)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana - SO/SI)")]
  Iso2022jpOneByte = 50222,
  /// <summary>Korean (ISO)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Korean (ISO)")]
  Iso2022kr = 50225,
  /// <summary>Chinese Simplified (ISO-2022)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Simplified (ISO-2022)")]
  Xcp50227 = 50227,
  /// <summary>Japanese (EUC)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Japanese (EUC)")]
  Eucjp = 51932,
  /// <summary>Chinese Simplified (EUC)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Simplified (EUC)")]
  EUCCN = 51936,
  /// <summary>Korean (EUC)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Korean (EUC)")]
  Euckr = 51949,
  /// <summary>Chinese Simplified (HZ)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Simplified (HZ)")]
  Hzgb2312 = 52936,
  /// <summary>Chinese Simplified (GB18030)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Chinese Simplified (GB18030)")]
  GB18030 = 54936,
  /// <summary>ISCII Devanagari</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Devanagari")]
  Xisciide = 57002,
  /// <summary>ISCII Bengali</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Bengali")]
  Xisciibe = 57003,
  /// <summary>ISCII Tamil</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Tamil")]
  Xisciita = 57004,
  /// <summary>ISCII Telugu</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Telugu")]
  Xisciite = 57005,
  /// <summary>ISCII Assamese</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Assamese")]
  Xisciias = 57006,
  /// <summary>ISCII Oriya</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Oriya")]
  Xisciior = 57007,
  /// <summary>ISCII Kannada</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Kannada")]
  Xisciika = 57008,
  /// <summary>ISCII Malayalam</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Malayalam")]
  Xisciima = 57009,
  /// <summary>ISCII Gujarati</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Gujarati")]
  Xisciigu = 57010,
  /// <summary>ISCII Punjabi</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("ISCII Punjabi")]
  Xisciipa = 57011,
  /// <summary>Unicode (UTF-7)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Unicode (UTF-7)")]
  Utf7 = 65000,
  /// <summary>Unicode (UTF-8)</summary>
  [DescriptionAttribute("Unicode (UTF-8)")]
  Utf8 = 65001
}
```

Comment: Please see this question on enumerating an enum in C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/enumerate-an-enum

Comment: This isn't really a question.  You should have asked a question about the lack of a `CodePage` `enum` and then posted this as an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the method I used, but I didn't know how to post this. I only thought it was an annoying job to do this and wanted to save this for anybody else... Sorry but why is it marked as maybe already answered?

Comment: You could just move the code to an answer.  Maybe reword the question a little bit and it should be fine.

Comment: @GlennFerrie I don't see how this has anything to do with enumerating the values of an `enum`.

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but you have to do it properly by first asking a question (in the question area). You can then post an answer (just like anyone else would) in the area marked *Your Answer* below. See [Can I answer my own question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information. This is not a "here's an article" site, or a blog site. It's a "question and answer" site, which means you have to ask a question before it can be answered. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't GitHub.

Comment: Note that many codepages have multiple names...

Comment: And you should strive for consistency in casing: `IBM437` vs `Ibm850`.