# foreach on enum with Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, linq, enums

How to iterate on enum and get Attribute & Values?

```
public enum TableName {
    [DescriptionWithValue("offline", "create table offline (uid int, date datetime, id int)")]
    Offline,
    [Description("Online","create table online (uid int, date datetime, id int)")]
    online,
    [Description("Amount","create table amount (uid int, date datetime, id int)")]
    amount
}
```

Comment: What did you try to do it? SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: [Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value), and [iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum) . I used a search engine.

Comment: @PatrickArtner This is a programming problem.

Comment: What @PatrickArtner means is for you to show what you have tried to do. How you've tried to implement that and where you are getting stumped or what error message is getting displayed when you try. It will be possible from there to point you in the right direction or fix the code as opposed to getting someone to write it for you from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            foreach (var field in typeof(TableName).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                ProcessField(field);
            }
        }

        static void ProcessField(FieldInfo field)
        {
            ProcessD(field.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute);
            ProcessDWV(field.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionWithValueAttribute)) as DescriptionWithValueAttribute);            
        }

        static void ProcessD(DescriptionAttribute attribute)
        {
            if(attribute != null)
            {
                //...
            }
        }

        static void ProcessDWV(DescriptionWithValueAttribute attribute)
        {
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
```