# C# 8 - CS8605 "Unboxing possibly null value" on enum

Tags: c#, .net-core, enums, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a project with `<nullable>enable</nullable>` in the .csproj
and I am experiencing some weird behavior of the warnings.

I have a foreach statement that iterates over an enum, and foreach item in the enum runs some code.
But VS2019 flags up the CS8605 "Unboxing possibly null value" warning when I try and do this.

[image]

Full code is shown here. The error displays over the deceleration of `t`.

```
public static class Textures
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<TextureSet, Texture2D> textureDict = new Dictionary<TextureSet, Texture2D>();

    internal static void LoadContent(ContentManager contentManager)
    {
        foreach(TextureSet t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TextureSet)))
        {
            textureDict.Add(t, contentManager.Load<Texture2D>(@"textures/" + t.ToString()));
        }
    }

    public static Texture2D Map(TextureSet texture) => textureDict[texture];
}
```

I'm struggling to understand why there is potential for `t` to be null as enums are non-nullable.
I'm wondering if, since `Enum.GetValues` returns of type `Array` if there is some implicit casting going on here that is the root of this problem.
My solution currently is just to suppress the warning. But I would like to understand what's going on here. Perhaps there is better way to iterate over an enum.

Comment: Note that this issue is expected to go away in .NET 5 because IEnumerator.Current has changed from an `object?` type to a nullable-oblivious `object` type. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/37918

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm wandering if, since `Enum.GetValues` returns of type `Array` if there
> is some implicit casting going on here that is the root of this
> problem.

You are right, there is an implicit casting that is made by the foreach loop. And it is the root of the problem.

As you've noted `Enum.GetValues` returns an object of type `Array`. With `nullable context` enabled items of the `Array` are of nullable type `object?`. When you iterate over an `Array` in a foreach loop each `Array` item is casted to the type of the iteration variable. In your case each `Array` item of type `object?` is casted to the type `TextureSet`. This cast produces the warning `Unboxing possibly null value`.

If you try your code in [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQAdYwggdsgZgBoATEAagB8ABAJgEYBYAKGoAYACa+gOgCUIYADYQAxjACWAe1wBuFiwDEuOEKFRgIjhFwaRC1gS60u9AOwsA3iwCQdWrevMbNsFKRRRACwAUAIQlcEkCAcwAxdRDkDhgOQI4AURUAWx4AcQgYADUoITgUHxgAT3QIKTB/QODccMjkAEpG2xsnFwBfWw7mNqA) you'll see that internally C# compiler transforms considered foreach loop to the while loop that clearly shows the problem (some code blocks I ommited for simplicity):

```
IEnumerator enumerator = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TextureSet)).GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    // Type of the enumerator.Current is object?, so the next line
    // casts object? to TextureSet. Such cast produces warning
    // CS8605 "Unboxing possibly null value".
    TextureSet t = (TextureSet) enumerator.Current;
}
```

> My solution currently is just to suppress the warning. ... Perhaps there is better way to iterate over an enum.

Also you can use the next [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105402/12833205) to fix the warning:

```
foreach (TextureSet t in (TextureSet[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(TextureSet)))
{
}
```