# Trying to iterate trough enum using foreach and witch case

Tags: c#, foreach, enums, switch-statement

I made enum and tried to go through it with for-each loop and look for different cases using switch case and get values of dives used.
ERROR I AM GETTING IS **cannot implicitly convert type'console5.typeOfDevice' to 'string'**

```
enum typeOfDevice
    {
        iphone=99,
        android=59,
        tablet=49
    }
var usedDevice = Enum.GetNames(typeof(typeOfDevice));
foreach (string used in usedDevice)
                {
                    switch (used)
                    {
                        case usedDevice.iphone: //gets error here
                            Console.Write($"enter how many time you used Iphone");
                            var input = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case usedDevice.android:
                            Console.Write($"enter how many time you used Android");
                            var input = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case usedDevice.tablet:
                            Console.Write($"enter how many time you used Tablet");
                            var input = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: what is the question / problem?

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type'console5.typeOfDevice' to 'string' getting this error

Comment: You would need to use `Enum.GetValues` rather than `Enum.GetNames`, but using an enum here doesn't seem necessary anyway.

Comment: used is a string so you need to test it against string type, like:
 case "iphone":

Answer (score 1):

`Enum.GetNames` [returns a string array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=net-5.0). In your loop, you are trying to get `usedDevice.iphone` (etc) but `usedDevice` is a string array, therefore you'll get an error. However, if you change `usedDevice` to `typeOfDevice`, you'll get the comparison error you've edited into your question.

Namely, `used` is of type string, and it cannot implicitly be converted to `typeOfDevice`, since `typeOfDevice` is an enum, and not a string.

[This question may be useful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum). In short, use `GetValues` over `GetNames`

Comment: Thank You It worked..